# Is listening to music halal?

Tags: halal-haram, music

As a Muslim person since birth, I have always heard that music is prohibited (Haram) by all scholars in TV, radio, books and recently on the internet until I have heard a session with [Sheikh Adel Alkablani](http://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%84_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%8A) (one of the Imams of Almasjid Alharam in Makkah).

He claimed that music itself is allowed (Halal), but what comes with the music is prohibited (haram) e.g. the dancing, mixing men with ladies, etc. He even supported his claim with proof. He also said as long as music does not prevent you from doing your prayers and other pillars of Islam then it is Halal. When I was doing research I found that there are others who believe in the same idea as sheikh Adel.

I could not find an English page with this claim, but if you read Arabic you can search in goggle and you will get a lot of results. I also find him in [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=coT1fwK1k-g) saying the same thing.

Now I am confused. Is Music Halal (permissible) or Haram (prohibited)?

Comment: This is an issue where there is a difference of opinion. I hope the accepted answer evenhandedly mentions both sides of the equation and not just one.

Comment: @Atif there's no accepted answer, and since OP deleted their account, there won't be.

Answer (score 41):

This is an issue on which scholars have differed.

The vast majority of scholars throughout time claim that music is haraam, and cite the references in the other answers. [Islam QA](http://islamqa.com/en/ref/170208) says:

> The four Imams, their followers and the vast majority of earlier
>   Muslim scholars are of the view that musical instruments are haraam,
>   to such an extent that it was narrated that there was consensus on
>   this issue.

[A hadith in Saheeh Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/urn/52420) states:

> From among my followers there will be some people who will consider
>   illegal sexual intercourse, the wearing of silk [for men], the drinking of
>   alcoholic drinks and the use of musical instruments, as lawful. [...]

Ibn Masood, the great companion, said: "Never will love of Qur'an and love of music coexist in the heart." So if you don't love Qur'an, which is the foundation of our religion, where does that leave you bro?

Therefore, only an exceedingly small minority believe it to be permissible.

However, understand the two different rulings: they differ from haram to mubah (permissible). In this case, the safer thing to do is avoid the difference of opinion and not fall into music. This comes from the hadith of rasulullah:

> That which is lawful is clear and that which is unlawful is clear, and
>   between the two of them are doubtful matters about which many people
>   do not know. Thus he who avoids doubtful matters clears himself in
>   regard to his religion and his honor, but he who falls into doubtful
>   matters [eventually] falls into that which is unlawful, like the
>   shepherd who pastures around a sanctuary, all but grazing therein. [...]

Collected by Imam Nawawi in his famous 40 hadith; it is [hadith #6](http://www.islaam.net/40hadeeth/display_hadeeth.php?number=6).

Comment: http://sunnah.com/urn/52420 There is also this hadith: heard the Prophet saying, "From among my followers there will be some people who will consider illegal sexual intercourse, the wearing of silk, the drinking of alcoholic drinks and the use of musical instruments, as lawful.

Comment: Citation needed for paragraphs 2 and 4. For paragraph 5, consider applying the same logic to other things before leaning towards so-called 'safety'.

Comment: @muntoo I have added sources. But I must say, your statement about "consider applying the same logic to other things before leaning towards so-called safety" seems antagonistic. Maybe you can explain what you mean so that we're clear what you're trying to say?

Comment: The second quote seems to be discounted [here](http://www.islamawareness.net/Music/music_fatwa002.html). Regarding what I said earlier: I think what you said *"...the safer thing to do is avoid the difference of opinion..."* is an opinion, not fact; one shouldn't forbid [oneself or others] from things that are not absolutely proven haram.

Comment: @muntoo the second quote is from Bukhari, which is the highest level of hadith. The third "opinion" is a hadith of rasulullah; again, not anyone's opinion.

Comment: Isnt there also one that says drums on days of celebration are ok. Isnt this conflicting? Can you add this Hadith then speak to it?

Comment: @Jason with any issue, there are various opinions and proofs on both sides. Scholars who follow the opinion which I've presented here use that to limit it to a) daff/drums/precussion only (depends on the scholar), and b) some say only for weddings (other say otherwise).

Answer (score 18):

This is a complicated and messy subject. I will try to be as objective as I can at my answer, in summary I will mention three different opinions along with their proofs:

- Music is Haram
- Music is Halal
- Music is Halal in accordance to Denatology
- My final opinion on the matter

## Music is Haram

### From Quran

Allah says:

[image]

> And of the people is he who buys the amusement of speech to mislead [others] from the way of Allah without knowledge and who takes it in ridicule. Those will have a humiliating punishment. [31:6]

`amusement of speech` has been [referenced](http://islamqa.info/ar/5000) as the following by the following people:

- Ibn Abbas PBUH: Singing
- Mogahed: Drums
- Alhassan Albasri: Singing and Flutes
- Ibn Masood: Singing
- Abi Omar PBUH: Singing

Allah also says:

[image]

> And incite [to senselessness] whoever you can among them with your voice and assault them with your horses and foot soldiers and become a partner in their wealth and their children and promise them." But Satan does not promise them except delusion. [17:64]

Same source as above, Moghaed claims that `your voice` references Singing and falsehood.

### From Sunnah

The prophet [says](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/74/16):

> وَقَالَ هِشَامُ بْنُ عَمَّارٍ حَدَّثَنَا صَدَقَةُ بْنُ خَالِدٍ، حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنُ يَزِيدَ بْنِ جَابِرٍ، حَدَّثَنَا عَطِيَّةُ بْنُ قَيْسٍ الْكِلاَبِيُّ، حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنُ غَنْمٍ الأَشْعَرِيُّ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنِي أَبُو عَامِرٍ ـ أَوْ أَبُو مَالِكٍ ـ الأَشْعَرِيُّ وَاللَّهِ مَا كَذَبَنِي سَمِعَ النَّبِيَّ صلى الله عليه وسلم يَقُولُ ‏ "‏ لَيَكُونَنَّ مِنْ أُمَّتِي أَقْوَامٌ يَسْتَحِلُّونَ الْحِرَ وَالْحَرِيرَ وَالْخَمْرَ وَالْمَعَازِفَ، وَلَيَنْزِلَنَّ أَقْوَامٌ إِلَى جَنْبِ عَلَمٍ يَرُوحُ عَلَيْهِمْ بِسَارِحَةٍ لَهُمْ، يَأْتِيهِمْ ـ يَعْنِي الْفَقِيرَ ـ لِحَاجَةٍ فَيَقُولُوا ارْجِعْ إِلَيْنَا غَدًا‏.‏ فَيُبَيِّتُهُمُ اللَّهُ وَيَضَعُ الْعَلَمَ، وَيَمْسَخُ آخَرِينَ قِرَدَةً وَخَنَازِيرَ إِلَى يَوْمِ الْقِيَامَةِ ‏"‏‏.‏
>
> that he heard the Prophet (ﷺ) saying, "From among my followers there will be some people who will consider illegal sexual intercourse, the wearing of silk, the drinking of alcoholic drinks and the use of musical instruments, as lawful. And there will be some people who will stay near the side of a mountain and in the evening their shepherd will come to them with their sheep and ask them for something, but they will say to him, 'Return to us tomorrow.' Allah will destroy them during the night and will let the mountain fall on them, and He will transform the rest of them into monkeys and pigs and they will remain so till the Day of Resurrection."

A small mention that the hadith was also [narrated from another source](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/34/20) missing the Musical instrument part.

The prophet also mentions that the selling of singers in 2 [hadiths](http://sunnah.com/search/?q=%D8%AA%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%B9%D9%88%D8%A7%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D9%8A%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%AA), both are weak:

> حَدَّثَنَا قُتَيْبَةُ، حَدَّثَنَا بَكْرُ بْنُ مُضَرَ، عَنْ عُبَيْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ زَحْرٍ، عَنْ عَلِيِّ بْنِ يَزِيدَ، عَنِ الْقَاسِمِ بْنِ عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ، وَهُوَ عَبْدُ الرَّحْمَنِ مَوْلَى عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ عَنْ أَبِي أُمَامَةَ عَنْ رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏"‏ لاَ تَبِيعُوا الْقَيْنَاتِ وَلاَ تَشْتَرُوهُنَّ وَلاَ تُعَلِّمُوهُنَّ وَلاَ خَيْرَ فِي تِجَارَةٍ فِيهِنَّ وَثَمَنُهُنَّ حَرَامٌ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ فِي مِثْلِ ذَلِكَ أُنْزِلَتْ عَلَيْهِ هَذِهِ الآيَةُ ‏:‏ ‏(‏ومِنَ النَّاسِ مَنْ يَشْتَرِي لَهْوَ الْحَدِيثِ لِيُضِلَّ عَنْ سَبِيلِ اللَّهِ ‏)‏ إِلَى آخِرِ الآيَةِ ‏.‏ قَالَ أَبُو عِيسَى هَذَا حَدِيثٌ غَرِيبٌ إِنَّمَا يُرْوَى مِنْ حَدِيثِ الْقَاسِمِ عَنْ أَبِي أُمَامَةَ ‏.‏ وَالْقَاسِمُ ثِقَةٌ وَعَلِيُّ بْنُ يَزِيدَ يُضَعَّفُ فِي الْحَدِيثِ قَالَ سَمِعْتُ مُحَمَّدَ بْنَ إِسْمَاعِيلَ يَقُولُ الْقَاسِمُ ثِقَةٌ وَعَلِيُّ بْنُ يَزِيدَ يُضَعَّفُ ‏.‏
>
> Narrated Abu Umamah: that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "Do not sell the female singers, nor purchase them, nor teach them (to sing). And there is no good in trade in them, and their prices are unlawful. It was about the likes of this that this Ayah was revealed: 'And among mankind is he who purchases idle talk to divert from the way of Allah (31:6).'"

Another Munkar [hadith](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/152), that was made Sahih by Alabani:

> حَدَّثَنَا أَحْمَدُ بْنُ عُبَيْدِ اللَّهِ الْغُدَانِيُّ، حَدَّثَنَا الْوَلِيدُ بْنُ مُسْلِمٍ، حَدَّثَنَا سَعِيدُ بْنُ عَبْدِ الْعَزِيزِ، عَنْ سُلَيْمَانَ بْنِ مُوسَى، عَنْ نَافِعٍ، قَالَ سَمِعَ ابْنُ عُمَرَ، مِزْمَارًا - قَالَ - فَوَضَعَ أُصْبُعَيْهِ عَلَى أُذُنَيْهِ وَنَأَى عَنِ الطَّرِيقِ وَقَالَ لِي يَا نَافِعُ هَلْ تَسْمَعُ شَيْئًا قَالَ فَقُلْتُ لاَ ‏.‏ قَالَ فَرَفَعَ أُصْبُعَيْهِ مِنْ أُذُنَيْهِ وَقَالَ كُنْتُ مَعَ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم فَسَمِعَ مِثْلَ هَذَا فَصَنَعَ مِثْلَ هَذَا ‏.‏ قَالَ أَبُو عَلِيٍّ اللُّؤْلُؤِيُّ سَمِعْتُ أَبَا دَاوُدَ يَقُولُ هَذَا حَدِيثٌ مُنْكَرٌ ‏.‏
>
> Nafi' said: Ibn Umar heard a pipe, put his fingers in his ears and went away from the road. He said to me: Are you hearing anything? I said: No. He said: He then took his fingers out of his ears and said: I was with the Prophet (ﷺ), and he heard like this and he did like this. AbuAli al-Lu'lu said: I heard AbuDawud say: This is a rejected hadith.

## Music is Halal

### From the Quran

Unfortunately, there is no proof from the explicitly allows Music. However, those are claim it is Halal do not go to extreme interruption of `amusement of speech` and `your voice` that was claimed above. If that was meant as Music, the Prophet PBUH would have made it crisp clear and not for his companions to interrupt it.

### From the Sunnah

It was [mentioned](http://sunnah.com/search/?q=%D8%AF%D9%8E%D8%B9%D9%92%D9%87%D9%8F%D9%85%D9%8E%D8%A7+%D9%8A%D9%8E%D8%A7+%D8%A3%D9%8E%D8%A8%D9%8E%D8%A7+%D8%A8%D9%8E%D9%83%D9%92%D8%B1%D9%8D) in several hadiths that:

> حَدَّثَنِي مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ الْمُثَنَّى، حَدَّثَنَا غُنْدَرٌ، حَدَّثَنَا شُعْبَةُ، عَنْ هِشَامٍ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ، عَنْ عَائِشَةَ، أَنَّ أَبَا بَكْرٍ، دَخَلَ عَلَيْهَا وَالنَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم عِنْدَهَا يَوْمَ فِطْرٍ أَوْ أَضْحًى، وَعِنْدَهَا قَيْنَتَانِ ‏{‏تُغَنِّيَانِ‏}‏ بِمَا تَقَاذَفَتِ الأَنْصَارُ يَوْمَ بُعَاثَ‏.‏ فَقَالَ أَبُو بَكْرٍ مِزْمَارُ الشَّيْطَانِ مَرَّتَيْنِ‏.‏ فَقَالَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ دَعْهُمَا يَا أَبَا بَكْرٍ، إِنَّ لِكُلِّ قَوْمٍ عِيدًا، وَإِنَّ عِيدَنَا هَذَا الْيَوْمُ ‏"‏‏.‏
>
> That once Abu Bakr came to her on the day of `Id-ul-Fitr or` Id ul Adha while the Prophet (ﷺ) was with her and there were two girl singers with her, singing songs of the Ansar about the day of Buath. Abu Bakr said twice. "Musical instrument of Satan!" But the Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Leave them Abu Bakr, for every nation has an `Id (i.e. festival) and this day is our` Id."

As you can clearly see the prophet PBUH allowed Musical instruments, if that haram he wouldn't allow it at times.

In another set of [hadiths](http://sunnah.com/search/?q=%D9%8A%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%A8%D9%88%D9%86%20%D9%81%D9%8A%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%AC%D8%AF), the prophet says:

> حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ الْعَزِيزِ بْنُ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا إِبْرَاهِيمُ بْنُ سَعْدٍ، عَنْ صَالِحٍ، عَنِ ابْنِ شِهَابٍ، قَالَ أَخْبَرَنِي عُرْوَةُ بْنُ الزُّبَيْرِ، أَنَّ عَائِشَةَ، قَالَتْ لَقَدْ رَأَيْتُ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم يَوْمًا عَلَى باب حُجْرَتِي، وَالْحَبَشَةُ يَلْعَبُونَ فِي الْمَسْجِدِ وَرَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم يَسْتُرُنِي بِرِدَائِهِ، أَنْظُرُ إِلَى لَعِبِهِمْ‏.‏ زَادَ إِبْرَاهِيمُ بْنُ الْمُنْذِرِ حَدَّثَنَا ابْنُ وَهْبٍ، أَخْبَرَنِي يُونُسُ، عَنِ ابْنِ شِهَابٍ، عَنْ عُرْوَةَ، عَنْ عَائِشَةَ، قَالَتْ رَأَيْتُ النَّبِيَّ صلى الله عليه وسلم وَالْحَبَشَةُ يَلْعَبُونَ بِحِرَابِهِمْ‏.‏
>
> Once I saw Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) at the door of my house while some Ethiopians were playing in the mosque (displaying their skill with spears). Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) was screening me with his Rida' so as to enable me to see their display. (`Urwa said that` Aisha said, "I saw the Prophet (ﷺ) and the Ethiopians were playing with their spears.")

Anyone who have watched ancient Ethopian dance songs, like most African dances, knows that it not included Musical instrument, but barely clothed warriors dancing with spears.

## Music is Halal in accordance to Denatology

This opinion, many would not like, but basically it is an overall modernization of Islamic logic of where it says that Allah claims in the Quran that it is complete, with all the rules and regulations:

[image]

> This day those who disbelieve have despaired of [defeating] your religion; so fear them not, but fear Me. This day I have perfected for you your religion and completed My favor upon you and have approved for you Islam as religion. But whoever is forced by severe hunger with no inclination to sin - then indeed, Allah is Forgiving and Merciful. [5:3]

Many claim that the Hadith is the same level as the word of God citing, which is incorrect. The Quran was meant as a complete Halal/Haram template. The Sunnah was meant to explain and interrupt the Quran and no more. The prophet PBUH will never make something Haram from a whim of his own, and if it was a revelation it would be in the Quran, as that is what the Quran is, a revelation of Allah's orders.

On such basis, the Music is not Haram since Allah did not forbid it explicitly in the Quran.

## My final opinion on the matter

Music itself is not Haram. However, the wording of the Music - which is not what the question asks can make it Haram or Halal. The same way as Knife is Halal but it's usage can make it Halal or Haram.

Comment: This is the same thing Sheikh al-Ghazaly (May Allah be merciful to him) wrote and he added the case with music is like poetry some maybe haram some halal! The last part of the statement is actually a hadith that was compiled by at-Tabarani.

Comment: What's the opinion of Ibn Abbas the onw to whom mst knowledge of the Qur'an was given? If the salaf viewed music as haram then they know better than the khalaf.

Comment: So I guess instrumental with no vocal is okay? I only listen to piano remixes.

Comment: @henna_ the salaf practiced music and singing. Yes not the sahbah, but music and singing where known to be practiced in al-Hijaz. And the argumentation of this sheikh is the same as that of ibn Hazm who even refuted any hadith saying otherwise and presented sahih narrations supporting his view. The point on which there's a consensus in the ummah is that a man is not allowed to listen to the singing of a foreign women.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I respect and trust Ibn Hazm at other matters, but at music, his claim of refuting the hadith of being weak/false is simply *wrong*. It's Ijma' (consensus) that music is haram by 4 madhhab.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Are you going to ignore that *any* tafsir book about 31:6 mentions that the sahabah Abdullah ibn Masʽud swears and repeats three times that this verse talks about singing with instruments?

Comment: I don't understand people with the logic of using the hadith "But the Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Leave them Abu Bakr, for every nation has an Id (i.e. festival) and this day is our Id." to make music halal. This hadith in fact *further proves* that music (with instruments) is haram regardless if the lyrics is not bad.

Comment: @Medi1Saif "the salaf practiced music and singing." Where did you get this? It's in fact the complete opposite.

Comment: @Adola See [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/56642/authenticity-of-hadith-similar-to-famous-hadith-on-end-of-times-in-bukhari/56649#56649) I've linked my source(s) too. Sheikh al-Ghazaly named known scholars of each of the four schools of fiqh who disagrees with the mainstream on the matter.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Yes he is one of the only 2 scholars (al-Ghazaly Hafizhahullah and Ibn Hazm Hafizhahullah) that I personally knew that says that it's halal. I highly respect those two scholars, but on the matter of music, they are wrong.

Comment: @Adola on what basis are they wrong? While a scholar such as al-Qadi abu Bakr ibn 'Araby (Maliki scholar, author of a Tafsir and commentator on hadith) in his Ahkam al-Qur'an says that none of the prohibiting texts are sahih, further ibn an-Nahwy, ibn Tahir, ibn Hazm and al-Ghazaly hold a similar view saying: on one hand none of the sahih sources explicitly prohibits singing, while none of the prohibiting texts are sahih. Imam a-Shatiby actually quoted in his al-'Itisaam a story of a man who used to sing after the prayer and 'Umar after asking him didn't say it is haram nor bid'ah to do so.

Comment: @Medi1Saif They are wrong for saying that it's not sahih, those people  made up a very small proportion. A *ton* experts in hadith like al-Bukhari, al-Barqani, Ibn Qayyim, 
 an-Nawawi, Ibn Hajar, Ibn Rajab, Ibn Taimiyya, asySyaukani, etc says it's sahih. The questions is why are they who says halal is wrong? Short story Ibn Hazm thought that the Sanad was disconnected (between al-Bukhari and Hisyam bin Ammar) and also 2 sahabah (Aby 'Amir and Abu Malik) which was not well-known. There are a lot of Muslim scholars like Ibn Qayyim or Muhammad Nasiruddin al-Albani who refuted those scholars.

Comment: @Medi1Saif By music is haram I meant with the *instruments*. Just singing without the instrument, is a different discussion.

Comment: @Adola al-Bukhari no where said so to start as that is the topic of my linked answer! Secondly except with ibn Hajar none of the quoted can be regarded as an expert on Jarh wa Ta'adeel, Ibn Hazm quoted much more than that. And as stated in the linked article of a hadith scholar, the quotation of al-Bukhari doesn't address  singing nor that of instruments it is rather the topic of drinking wine and calling it differently anything else is a baseless conclusion. And imam a-Dhahabi in his Siyar actually quoted a lot of singers who were hufadh too. Your statement of ibn Mas'ud is only his opinion.

Comment: This will by my last comment. There are so much wrong so I'll focus on only the critical one about Ibn Mas'ud. Ibn Mas'ud is a sahabah my friend. It's not like he's mentally ill for misunderstanding what the prophet's says. "only his opinion" isn't a refutation in the slightest bit. If you are going to cite *names of scholars* without bothering much about *Qur'an* (and hadith) then it's an unwise choice. I can mention names of "Muslim" scholars who says that Christians, Jews, etc go to heaven, scholars who approved Nikah mut'ah, killing any disbeliever, rape, etc.

Comment: "Many claim that the Hadith is the same level as the word of God citing, which is incorrect. The Quran was meant as a complete Halal/Haram template. The Sunnah was meant to explain and interrupt the Quran and no more. The prophet PBUH will never make something Haram from a whim of his own, and if it was a revelation it would be in the Quran, as that is what the Quran is, a revelation of Allah's orders"

Prophet (PBUH) did have things revealed to him via Jibreel AS, besides the Qur'an, there are Hadith E Qudsi.

Secondly, the Prophet (PBUH) has authority to define Halal and Haram.

Comment: For example, the Prophet (PBUH) defined Sorakha (RA) permissible to wear gold bracelets from Rome, even though he was a man, and there are other examples too like the permissibility of fish, etc.

Comment: Your interpretation of the statement "Leave them Abu Bakr, for every nation has an Id (i.e. festival) and this day is our Id." is very odd. Does this sound like a universal declaration of permissibility to you? I recommend reading the Hadiths before spamming them into a post.

Answer (score 10):

There is a related Bukhari hadith:

> Sahih Al-Bukhari Hadith 2.70 Narrated by Aisha
>
> Allah's Messenger (saws) came to my house while two small girls were singing beside me the songs of Buath (a story about the war between the two tribes of the Ansar, the Khazraj and the Aus, before Islam). The Prophet (saws) lay down and turned his face to the other side. Then Abu Bakr came and spoke to me harshly saying, "Musical instruments of the Shaytaan near the Prophet (saws)?"  Allah's Messenger (saws) turned his face towards him and said, "Leave them." When Abu Bakr became inattentive, I signaled to those girls to go out and they left. It was the day of 'Id, and the black people were playing with shields and spears; so either I requested the Prophet (saws) or he asked me whether I would like to see the display. I replied in the affirmative. Then the Prophet (saws) made me stand behind him and my cheek was touching his cheek and he was saying, "Carry on! O Bani Arfida," till I got tired. The Prophet (saws) asked me, "Are you satisfied (Is that sufficient for you)?" I replied in the affirmative and he (saws) told me to leave.

**In the opinion of Sufis listening to music is permissible, and in fact desirable, if listening increases a person's devotion to God; and it is not permissible if it has the opposite effect.**

Once, the Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) was asked about odes and poetry and he replied:

> They are merely words. As such, they can be either good or bad.

The Sufi saint Ali Hujwiri said:

> "Once when I was in Merv, one of the leading traditionalists said to me, 'I have written a book to demonstrate that listening to music is permissible.' I replied, 'A great difficulty has appeared in the faith. A noted leader has legitimized that frivolity which is the root of all wickedness.' 'If you don't consider it lawful,' he retorted, 'then why do you practice it?' I declared: 'Any instruction concerning it must depend on the circumstances. No blanket statement can be made about it. If listening to music produces a laudable effect in one's heart, then it is lawful. If its effects are unlawful, so too is it. Likewise, if the effects of listening are permissible, so is the listening.'

Likewise for dancing, Imam Ghazali has cited three reasons for dancing:

> The command about dancing refers to what moves a person to dance. if something praiseworthy stimulates a person to dance, and the dancing helps him grow, and strengthens him, then the dancing is also praiseworthy. If something despicable stimulates him to dance, then the dance also is despicable. But if it is something permissible that inspires him, then the dance also is permissible.

He also said:

> It became customary for a group of companions to dance for joy when anything wonderful happened.

Comment: You should give a warning though, today's music is almost about bad things.

Answer (score 9):

Asalamu wa alaikum,

> There will be people of my Ummah who will seek to make lawful; fornication, wine-drinking and the use of ma'aazif ( musical instruments ).
>
> [Bukari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/74/16)

In Islam, wind and string Musical instruments are haram, and Music sung by adult women (for men).

Primary source: Islamic online university

Comment: Isnt there also one that says drums on days of celebration are ok. Isnt this conflicting? Can you add this Hadith then speak to it?

Comment: Mostly the emphasis is on instruments with 'strings'.

Comment: As Salaamu 3laykum, this is not the only viewpoint on this matter.

Answer (score 3):

According to Mufti Menk, most scholars agree with one another that music today is haraam for it encourages dirty words, sexual bodily movements and bad actions. That when some scholars of the past have said that music is ok; they meant music of the past not the music that's around today. Those involved in the musical industry (ie Madonna, Elton John etc) are involved in unlawful things.

https://youtu.be/YDrPbgE9h58

Allah is totally against zina (adultery) and all that leads to it (thus we should lower our gaze to the opposite sex, cover our private parts, being alone with the opposite gender is haraam if non mahram, unnecessary interaction with the opposite gender if non mahram etc) and as we can see from Mufti Menk's statement above this would also include music. Because music can lead to altered thoughts and thus lead to sexual desires and the committing of unlawful actions

“And do not (even) come near to adultery, for it is a shameful deed and an evil, opening the road (to other evils).” (al-Isra:32)

A woman's voice for men can arouse sexual desires (ie recitation of The Qu'ran and singing). Thus a woman has to recite The Qu'ran quietly when a non-mahram male is around and shouldn't sing in front of them:

“O wives of the prophet! You are not like other women, if you are god-fearing. So do not be soft in speech. Lest in whose heart is disease should be moved with desire.” (al-Ahzab:32)

“It is permissible for women to converse with non-Mahram men at the time of need (and vice versa). However, what is not permissible is that they stretch, soften and raise their voice in a melodious way.” (Radd al-Muhtar, V.1, P. 406)

And much more is also mentioned on this issue so this should be clear enough to know that music is forbidden. That most of the scholars are of that view. Singing itself without music (not done in front of non-Mahram opposite sex) is permissible as shown above, obviously putting in words of benefit not anything evil.

So the above summarizes these points:

1. music today in all instances is haraam (forbidden) as it can lead to adultery caused through sexual desires and thoughts, evil words used, sexual bodily movements and altered thoughts
2. singing without music is halaal (permissible) where not done in front of the non-mahram of the opposite sex and using beneficial words while avoiding any evil words or words that may lead to evil actions
3. music affects concentration as it impairs the thought (thus leading to indecent sinful things)
4. music is linked to body movements (this could also include sexual bodily movements and an inability to control the body's movements)

The reason for no beat necessary nasheeds also.

Now through experience if I am in a room or walking in a shop or down the street and music is playing, I start to feel special within me and powerful and my body starts to move uncontrollably. Over 20 years ago when I was at high school I remember some music being put on at break time and there was this pupil started laughing and said to another pupil "look at the idiot trying to dance" about me but I wasn't, it was the effect of music on my body. Allah knows. So seriously it is a bad thing

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 1):

Let me clear the background before answering this question first by answering few questions:
1. What is Haram in Islam?
2. Who created Music?
3. Reference in Scriptures.
4. Why Music?
5. Why The Conflict?

1. Haram : Everything created by Allah is perfect and have a purpose but the use of them make them halal and haram. So Allah had given the lower and upper limits to use them such that they don't harm you by excessive use.

   - Food is very good in itself and Eating is a need and necessity which is in innate nature of human being and it has a very specific purpose in life. But if we OVEREAT something it causes chaos in the body. So there is a upper limit to that which is mentioned by the beloved Prophet.
   - Knowledge is very good but if not used properly may cause selfishness, clashes of Ego and even destruction of nature. So an upper limit of that is given by Allah and how to use it.
   - Things which are the basic necessity and need of human being which comes by birth to him are not made haram in Quran.

     - Sex is a human need gifted to human being to reproduce. It is a basic need of human being that's why not made haram in Quran. Rather Allah Subhan-o-taala provided the way to accomplish it by marrying. Often the question comes of love marriage and arranged marriage and our generation prefer love but we can see that both often fail. Why? Because it's not about love or arranged but about the freedom to choose your wife or husband which is given by Islam.
   - Haram can only be declared by the one who created those things and the Creator is only Allah. Prophet is the implementor and an ideal.
2. Music already existed and definitely created by The Almighty Creator and we used it to ease and please ourselves in various ways, so by default it is not haram but if it's use makes you loose your aim, your purpose of life for which you have been created as a muslim and the part of the Ummah then definitely it is harming you.

   - Look at the people who are at great place in their lives. They are their because they follow some rules. A few of them are being crystal clear about what they want to do in their life. Firm determination, Hardwork, Focused. You may not see them most of the time listening music because they have an aim to achieve. But often they do it to refresh themselves. But that is not even a 1% of their part in their life.
   - A Muslim is always on a mission and a part of the Ummah if he does good and forbids evil. So it is damn necessary to be focussed. Which is often lost by overlistning music. Because you have not achieved your aim yet.
3. Quran does not mentions music explicitly which means Allah Definitely did not intend to do that. Because it is not that big deal. Obviously you know what you want to do if you have a serious aim to achieve. But it mentions about the people of jannah will enter it 'very happy and Joyful'. Hadiths:

   - Narrated Aisha: Abu Bakr came to my house while two small Ansari girls were singing beside me the stories of the Ansar concerning the Day of Buath. And they were not singers. Abu Bakr said protestingly, "musical instruments of Satan in the house of Allah's Apostle !" It happened on the 'Id day and Allah's Apostle said, "O Abu Bakr! There is an 'Id for every nation and this is our 'Id."  (Book #15, Hadith #72)
   - Narrated Abu Musa: That the Prophet said to him' "O Abu Musa! You have been given one of the musical wind-instruments of the family of David .'  (Book #61, Hadith #568)
   - Quran 17:55 "And it is your Lord that knoweth best all beings that are in the heavens and on earth: We did bestow on some prophets more (and other) gifts than on others: and We gave to David the Psalms." Pslams means: A collection of sacred poems forming a book of canonical Jewish and Christian Scripture. Through which Daud (a.s.) praises the lord.
   - Muslim narrated from Abu Hurayrah, he said: The Messenger of Allah, peace be upon him, said: 'He is not one of us that does not SING with Qur'an'; others added ‘spoke out of it.'
4. Music is something which if is beautiful will HYPNOTIZE you and take you to the TRANCE mode. When you start your salah as prescribed by prophet (your salah should be like you are watching Allah or else like he is watching you) and you cut yourself from the whole world behind the Imam focussing towards ONE CREATOR and listening to what he says as Quran is recited without any second thought coming to your mind, that where you go in trance and you life turns and the real salah starts, because their you get connected to him.
5. Conflict is because we will find hadiths which prohibits music too very hardly but we will get also in support it. Actually these are the upper and lower limits mentioned by the Prophet at different occasions. Everyone is sticking to the part which they follow but the point is Allah tells in Quran that previous people made lawful things prohibited on themselves which were made lawful by Allah.  At the End:

   - Islam teaches you a perfect blend of balance in life which is only possible if you know what are you doing?, why are you doing that?, what is the purpose of doing that?
     And remember the first priority is to make Allah happy and Allah wants everyone to be happy and free, so have to serve humanity in order to serve Allah with an intention that i am doing it because my Rab likes it.
   - Beloved Prophet said that 'Man's beauty is in his tongue'. So using ill words is not allowed. Allah orders Momin in Quran to 'Unzurna' rather than saying 'Raeena'. Which means to use words which are clear and does not have double meanings and double standard.
     So if the music contains something which is unlawful in these means is definitely not a good habit. We ourself often don't use words which we listen in music in front of our parents because they are having double standards.
   - Like listening to Dr. Iqbal is a boon to me because his words make me more closer to Allah.

Answer (score 1):

From Shia-Islam view: (E.g. according to Ayatollah Khamenei, as a famous Marja'-al-Taqlid of Shia):

> A music is considered as a Haram Music that --according to Urf
> (custom)-- to be regarded as a Music of "لهوی مضل عن سبیل الله
> (Pleasure which is deceptive from the way of Allah)" that is suitable
> with debauchery/luxury meetings or parties; and there isn't difference
> if it is a classic or non-classic music. The realization of this issue
> is related to the Urfi view of the Mokalaf (obligated person);
> otherwise is is not a (haram) music per se if is not based on what was
> mentioned.

Or in brief (in other word): Any type of Mutrib music which befits carouse gatherings is haram.

**Source:**

[http://farsi.khamenei.ir](http://farsi.khamenei.ir/treatise-content?id=99&pid=99&tid=-1)

https://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa1590

Answer (score 0):

In Islam, the issue of Music has diverse opinions but there is a unanimous agreement that music that contains haram, promotes haram, is used for haram, and/or is done in unison with haram is haram.

Primary Islamic opinions regarding the permissibility of music:

- Music is haram
- Music is permissible
- Music is permissible in certain instances

I'm going to elaborate on each one from trustworthy sources and scholarly opinions.

## Music is Haram

**Some Famous Scholars that Say Music is Haram**

- Ibn Abbas
- Al-Hasan al-Basri
- Ibn al-Qayyim
- Ibn Taymiyah

**Evidence used in the Quran**

The ayahs used in the Quran to support to prohibition of music are the one's that speak negatively of idle talk which some scholars have interpreted "idle talk" to contain singing:

[Quran 31:6](https://quran.com/31?startingVerse=6)

> But there are some who employ theatrics, only to lead others away from Allah’s Way—without any knowledge—and to make a mockery of it. They will suffer a humiliating punishment.

[Quran 17:64](https://quran.com/17?startingVerse=64)

> And incite whoever you can of them with your voice, mobilize against them all your cavalry and infantry, manipulate them in their wealth and children, and make them promises.” But Satan promises them nothing but delusion.

Only a couple out of the dozens of exegetes thought these ayahs had anything to do with musical instruments.

**Evidence used in Hadith**

There are multiple hadiths that perceives music negatively and are used as a justification for prohibition. The most popular hadith used is [Sahih Bukhari 5590](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5590)

> Narrated Abu 'Amir or Abu Malik Al-Ash'ari:
> that he heard the Prophet (ﷺ) saying, "From among my followers there will be some people who will consider illegal sexual intercourse, the wearing of silk, the drinking of alcoholic drinks and the use of musical instruments, as lawful. And there will be some people who will stay near the side of a mountain and in the evening their shepherd will come to them with their sheep and ask them for something, but they will say to him, 'Return to us tomorrow.' Allah will destroy them during the night and will let the mountain fall on them, and He will transform the rest of them into monkeys and pigs and they will remain so till the Day of Resurrection."

**Sources**

- [Is Music Haram?](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/5000/is-music-haram#al-daff-an-appropriate-exception)
- [Is music haram in islam?](https://halalqa.com/music-haram-islam/)

## Music is Halal

**Some Famous Scholars that Say Music is Halal and their works about it**

- Abdullah bin Ja’far bin Abi Talib (al-Aqd al-Fareed 6/12)
- Sh. Abu Hamed al-Ghazali (vol. 6 pg. 1150 al-Ihyaa’)
- Imam al-Shawkani (Ibtal da’wa al-Ijmaa ala mutlaq al-Sama’)
- Imam ibn Hazm (Al-Muhallah)
- Imam Abdul-Ghani al-Nablusi (Idaahat al-Dalalaat fee sama’ al-alaat)
- Sultan al-Ulema al-Iz ibn Abdul-Salam (Rislat al-Sama’)
- Al-Qadi Ibn Qutaiba al-Daynoor (al-Rukhsah fi al-Sama’)
- Imam Ibn Tahir al-Qaysirany (pg. 31 al-Sama’)
- Imam al-Thahabi (al-Rukhsah fil-Ghinaa wa al-Turb)
- Abu Talib al-Makky (Qoot al-Quloob)
- al-Qady Ibn Al-Araby al-Makky (Ahkam al-Quran vol. 3 pg. 1494)
- Sh. Yusuf al-Majishoon the prominent Muhaddith (#3399 ibn al-Khuthayma)
- Ibn Daqeeq al-Eid (Iqtinas al-Sawanih)
- Sh. Jad Ali jad al-Haqq (fatawah #3280)
- Sh. Mahmood Al-Shaltoot (pg. 375 fatawaah)
- Yusuf al-Qaradawi in his book "The Lawful and the Prohibited in Islam", states songs/singing is not haram unless:

  1. the subject matter of songs is "against the teachings of Islam", such as praising wine;
  2. the "manner" of singing is haram, such as "being accompanied by suggestive sexual movement";
  3. it leads to "excessive involvement with entertainment", such as wasting time that ought to be spent on religion;
  4. if it "arouses one's passions, leads him towards sin, excites the animal instincts, and dulls spirituality";
  5. if it is done "in conjunction with haram activities – for example, at a drinking party".

**Evidence used in the Quran**

In the Quran, there's no explicit prohibition on music.

In [Quran 31:6](https://quran.com/31?startingVerse=6), Many exegetes took the more common path of general meaning (of "idle talk") in the absence of an authentic text and said it refers to preferring or liking to listen to false speech, thus distracting one from Islam.

The vast majority of exegetes said it is talking about the singing of jahiliyyah (pre-Islamic days). Imam al-Qurtubi said that this and the other verse ([Quran 17:64](https://quran.com/17?startingVerse=64)) are those that the scholars use as evidence for the disliked (مكروه) nature of singing. Imam al-Qurtubi also narrates that this verse was revealed in the life of the Prophet ﷺ when a man bought a slave known for singing unIslamic songs of jahiliyyah (ignorance).

**Evidence used in Hadith**

The most popular hadith used in justifying prohibition of music or declaring music is haram is [Sahih Bukhari 5590](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5590). But there happens to be multiple criticisms of this hadith's isnad (chain of narration).

1. Some hadith scholars found a connected chain for this type of hadith. The most famous is the book by Ibn Hajr in his book “closing the attachments” (تغليق التعليق). There are scholars who argued against his assertions, but even if we were to accept his findings about a connection between al-Bukhari and Hisham bin Ammar there is still a problem with Hisham as a narrator among some prominent hadith scholars.
2. Another narrator in this isnad that some prominent hadith scholars had an issue with was Atiyah bin Qays because of his imprecise memory.

Also, there are a few hadiths that show that Prophet Muhammad (SAW) showed a tolerance for music such as Sahih Bukhari 952 which has a stronger isnad than Sahih Bukhari 5590:

[Sahih Bukhari 952](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:952)

> Narrated Aisha:
> Abu Bakr came to my house while two small Ansari girls were singing beside me the stories of the Ansar concerning the Day of Buath. And they were not singers. Abu Bakr said protestingly, "Musical instruments of Satan in the house of Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) !" It happened on the `Id day and Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "O Abu Bakr! There is an `Id for every nation and this is our `Id."

**Sources and interesting Links**

- [Regarding the Permissibility of Music](https://www.virtualmosque.com/islam-studies/sciences-of-quran-and-hadith/regarding-the-permissibility-of-music/)
- [Listening to Music is Permissible in Islam](https://hawramani.com/listening-to-music-is-permissible-in-islam/)
- [Singing and playing musical instruments is permissible in Islam](https://hawramani.com/singing-and-playing-musical-instruments-is-permissible-in-islam/)
- [Singing and Music in Islam](https://www.islamicity.org/3018/singing-and-music-in-islam/)

## Music is permissible in certain instances

**Some Famous Scholars that have a mixed opinion on music**

- Dr. Zakir Naik
- Abu Bakr ibn al-Arabi

**Evidences**

A common opinion in this group is that singing is allowed because the hadiths made nor the Quran made any explicit prohibition on singing. That's why there are many nasheeds artists out there that utilize the human voice to create nasheeds.

Another common opinion in this group is that two specific instruments, the daff and tambourine, are exceptions to the prohibition on music stated in [Sahih Bukhari 5590](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5590) because of the Prophet Muhammad (SAW) allowing the two small girls to continue playing their instruments in his house as stated in [Sahih Bukhari 952](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:952).

**Sources**

- [Is Music Permitted in Islaam? – Dr Zakir Naik](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fjeczXPnIHg)
- [Singing and Music in Islam](https://www.islamicity.org/3018/singing-and-music-in-islam/)

Answer (score -1):

In order to understand how Islam/Quran/Allah addresses any matter is to understand first that Allah's direction to Humans is "Siraat Al-Mustaqeem" (The middle path) avoiding the two opposite extremes.

Now coming to getting involved in any activities where you are the content recipient such as:

- Watching Music Videos
- Watching Movie
- Watching News
- Watching Lectures
- Listening Music
- Listening Audio Books (Novel, Lectures etc.)
- Reading Books
- Reading Comics (graphics)

You need to make sure that the content it includes does not violate any principles set by Allah such as - men/women revealing body, immoral language etc. so that those practices do not influence you in a way that you start following them.

And then Once the above is clear, we come to the principle which has mostly influenced Muslims to call Music/TV haram and this has to do with verse 31:6:

Verse Translation:

> "But there are, among men, those who purchase amusing tales, without
> knowledge (or meaning), to mislead (men) from the Path of Allah and
> throw ridicule (on the Path): for such there will be a Humiliating
> Penalty"

So if you are paying to receive any content which (even though you are unaware of that) then misleads people from the Quranic path or ridicule the path then it is a big sin.

This would also include forgetting Salah and other mandatory practices when you are involved in that amusement.

**So this would be one extreme where you are involved too much.**

**The other extreme is you boycotting any involvement in any amusement** - all music, movie, TV etc. Which would again be wrong interpretation because music & dancing was allowed by Prophet himself on big occasions such as weddings and Eid etc.

So Entertainment has a place in Islam so don't boycott it completely and Entertainment has a limit too in Islam so don't overdo it.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know the things that harm your body or mind or Iman as being Muslim is haram.
If you hear music you are harming your ear, i,e; you are harming your body.

Again, there are many musics which contain bad words and these days you will hardly find any music which do not contain bad words or bad concepts which leads a Muslim to the wrong way.

Comment: I don't think you can "harm your body" by hearing music. (Assuming that it isn't blasted into your ears at jet engine volumes.) Also, citations.

Comment: What about instrumentals, music that doesn't contain words?  What about Mozart?

Comment: @muntoo Well, if you actually research about it, you will definitely find how hearing music harms your ear. I recommend you check the following site: [How can listening to music harm hearing?](http://ec.europa.eu/health/opinions/en/hearing-loss-personal-music-player-mp3/l-3/9-music-hearing-damage.htm)

Comment: @Ozon Thanks. Now if you really want to go damage your hearing, go live in a city. Far more damage than listening to music at safe levels especially with in-ear/noise-isolating earphones. In fact -- I'd argue that putting those isolating earphones on might actually be beneficial for your hearing because of it filtering out that horrid background city noise (especially true for me). Also, unlike most people, the lowest setting possible on my android wasn't good enough so I got an app to tweak it down further. Music's positive effects however: mental, spiritual, and physical (placebo).

Comment: lol, if you want to damage your hearing, live in Makkah/Medina. The car horns throughout the day are louder than many radios. Does that make it haraam to live in the holy city? I don't think noise is a good reason, and the majority of music doesn't have any bad words or bad influence.

Comment: You could also harm your ear by listening to bad recordings of speeches of sheikh Kiskh or Quran recitations! By the way Imam Malik (May Allah be merciful to him) wanted to become a singer: this is for me a clear statement which shows that music can't be haram as it was accepted even in the early days of islam

Answer (score -2):

Have you heard of the term لهو و لعب meaning ' play and amusement?

Surah Muhammad: 36
إِنَّمَا الحَيَاةُ الدُّنْيَا لَعِبٌ وَلَهْوٌ وَإِن تُؤْمِنُوا وَتَتَّقُوا يُؤْتِكُمْ أُجُورَكُمْ وَلَا يَسْأَلْكُمْ أَمْوَالَكُمْ
the life of this world is but play and amusement: and if ye believe and guard against evil, he will grant you your recompense, and will not ask you (to give up) your possessions.

Music is of this kind...and its not a thing that brings more fear of Allah its actually the antithesis of God-fearing. When you read Quran or a supplication you are reminded of the hereafter but if you listen to Music... its takes you into a trance mode that makes you forget Allah!

because of actually taking that God-fearing element away its Haram.

Answer (score -2):

I would say for every deed,everything about it like its content,features,purpose,intentions,etc could be seen by allah.The way allah work can be beyond human comprehension.If music does harm,it becomes an evil deed.If music does good it can become a good deed.Allah knows whats right and whats wrong.
The day of judgement might be what you are expecting,might not be what you are expecting or even somewhere in between.Allah is very competent.
There are many possibilities.Allah created freewill and everything goes according to his will.If music does something good even after harming someone or something or a person doesnt know or understand if music is good or bad or is misguided,allah will fairly judge according to the person's religious beleifs or maybe something different.Allah can easily punish someone for listening to music at any time but he chooses not to.One reason could be that person was misguided or one day would give up the sin.Allah is very competent.
The difference between adhaan,praises to allah and the prophets in poetry,and normal music is very debatable.Allah knows and decides in a way known or unknown to mankind.The day of judgement might be beyond human comprehension.

Answer (score -2):

I don't have the knwledge or authority to quote literature, but I want to post some facts and a couple of speculation. I would be thankful if you comment to educate me further in this matter.

---

Summary:
My two speculations are:

1. Perhaps Islam doesnt have conflict with music until and unless it promotes illicit acts. And almost certainly the ancient people of Islam had profound understanding of ancient microtonal musical scales.
2. Perhaps it is the slave trade that objectified music as matter of exploitation of women, from which music started to lose its spiritual value.

---

In my answer I would exclude most kind of ultra modern music that promote rampant sex, drugs, sucidal ideation etc, ultra loud dj sound boxes and cacophonic noise.

Yes, I avidly listen all form of ancient and classical music, especially Arabic and middle Eastern music, Sufi music as well as folk and tribal music, etc. and this includes instrumental music. The only reason for that - it reminds me of The Almighty. it reminds me the vastness of the ocean, it reminds me the broadness of the outer space. And that vibes are quite similar to Azaan (The call for prayer) that is sung by following [Arabic Maqams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_maqam). It doesn't seem at all there are any conflict in between music and the Art of chanting Islamic prayers.

Here is an good informative article about applications of traditional Arabic Maqams in recital of the Holy scriptures

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/345177847_Musical_Performance_Of_The_Holy_Quran_With_Assistance_Of_The_Arabic_Maqams

Also there is a book reference in http://www.fact-archive.com/encyclopedia/Adhan

> Each phrase is followed by a longer pause and is repeated one or more times according to fixed rules. During the first statement each phrase is limited in tonal range, less melismatic, and shorter. Upon repetition the phrase is longer, ornamented with melismas, and may possess a tonal range of over an octave. The adhan's form is characterised by contrast and contains twelve melodic passages which move from one to another tonal center of one maqam a fourth or fifth apart. The tempo is mostly slow; it may be faster and with less melismas for the sunset prayer. During festivals it may be performed antiphonally as a duet.

The second website refers to the book
*Habib Hassan Touma (1996). The Music of the Arabs, trans. Laurie Schwartz. Portland, Oregon: Amadeus Press. ISBN 0931340888.*

Unfortunately I couldn't access the book in Google books preview.

I strongly feel that the noble people who first sang the Azaans might not had any conflict with music. Probably they had great knowledge and grasp of Arabic microtonal scales (Arabic Maqams) that require deep understanding of the Music theory.

After a close look to [this answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/26369/51761), it looks like there were significant reason when music became controversial. It is Slave trade.  It can be fairly speculated that slaves specially women slaves were started to being used as object of entertainment, which probably included forceful dancing and singing. So music started to lose its spiritual value.

Here is a quote from the book Music and Musicians in the Medieval Islamicate World
A Social History, by Lisa Nielson it shows

> Enslaved women typically stood in as "temporary wives." In addition to visiting
> singing slave women, men would purchase slaves while traveling. Ibn Battuta, for
> example, purchased several slaves on his travels, reselling some and losing others.
> See Marina Tolmacheva, "Concubines on the Road: Ibn Battuta's Slave Women,"
> in Matthew Gordon and Kathryn Hain (eds.), Concubines and Courtesans: Women and Slavery in Islamic History (Oxford: Oxford University Press, 2017), 163-89.

Unfortunately, religion is not exactly history. Any religion is highly allegorical; and any allegory can have multiple interpretations. It seems many informations behind the folds of complications basically lost with time.

I value everyone. I value those who don't want to listen music, I value those who learn, teach and practice music, I value all the cultures and diversities that been celebrated by tribal people, muslims, non-muslims. I believe in humanity and personal freedom. Everyone should get what they need. And nobody should be oppressed nor deprived nor restricted from what they need.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I will try my best. Thank you

Comment: @Community how is the answer now? Is it improved?

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, prophet (s.a) didn't explicitly mention the musical instruments that are allowed and that are not allowed. Also, he didn't mention in which all situations any musical instrument(s) can be used. (like in Eid, weddings..) . These rulings are created by later scholars who go through hadiths and when they see a particular instrument being used in a particular situation, they say that instrument is allowed in that situation. Problem is not all situations and instruments get recorded in the hadith and we cannot say all other instruments and situations it is forbidden. Like in modern world music is generated electronically and we have them in our ring tones, calling bells, computer start up/shut down etc. We cannot categorically say all this are forbidden (haraam) because it is not mentioned in hadith.

We should be very careful when declaring something as forbidden or allowed (haraam or halaal)

> But say not - for any false thing that your tongues may put forth,-
> "This is lawful, and this is forbidden," so as to ascribe false things
> to Allah. For those who ascribe false things to Allah, will never
> prosper. Quran 16:116

Answer (score -3):

Instrumental(with out 2 or 3 instrumen) Music is haram!! But  which is not is not instrumental it is halal.
There's a hadith that one day prophet (PBUH) went to a marraige ceremony of a man.and it was boring there.so,He said to sing song as it's a joyful moment.
So, music without instrument halal.
.
But if u get addicted with a thing and for that reason u miss salah,u become far from Allah,it becomes haram for u for that time. I.e. Reading novel,listening song.

Comment: Please consider adding references to support your claims.

Answer (score -3):

By definition; Calling azan and reciting Quran with beautiful voices (human only) is also music -

Music definition: 6. An aesthetically pleasing or harmonious sound or combination of sounds: Source: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/music

I'm not a scholar but IMPOV if the interpretation of frequencies of sound waves and digital images (numeric representation, normally binary) is sinful then it's haram

Answer (score -3):

Simply, if music increases your devotion  and reminds you about your Allah and your deeds, it is Halal. And so is the opposite haram. The music also should not contain explicit words and words that contains shirk. If we take example of our Holy Quran, it is clear that the rhythm of Quran presents a kind of music and the Quran itself states that you should recite Quran with tajweed and, obviously tajweed presents a kind of rhythm.

Comment: This answer could profit from evidences to support your claims!

Comment: Do you have any evidence against my claims @Medi1Saif?

Comment: I understand your advice but if my claim is not right, it's also not wrong.

Answer (score -3):

We should see this issue in the context of most important saying of Holy Prophet PBUH when he was appointing a governor of Yemen to  sahaba named Muadh and asked him. How will decide your on going affairs. The sahabi replied that I will decide as prescribed in Quran. The Holy Prophet PBUH again asked if it is not clearly mentioned in quran, what will you do.  The sahabi replied that I will get guidance from Sunnah (Hadith).The holy prophet again asked if It even not included in Hadith what will your action. The sahabi again replied I will get guidence from collective wisdom of Islamic scholars and according to their findings will decide.The holy Prophet thereupon pettedhis back and told him that he is right (Sunan Abu Dawad).
The collective wisdom of renowned scholar is called ijtihad. Unfortunately if the continuation of ijtihad remains present such type of confussions among Muslims will not exist and clear opionon on oging day to day issues will present to follow throughout the Muslim world.

Now come towards our question. My opinion is as Islam is last and global religion and it's principles will be followed upto the end of this universe,  it mainly provides only principles not specific orders for the issues except for few issues like prohibtion of alcohol etc which is clearly defined in Quran.For these  issues including Music will be seen in light of Islamic teachings of Haram and Halal. If the factor of evil is not available than the action will be categorized as Halal. I want to quote the example of Muslim women.It is obligatory for the women not to attend the mixed gatherings where non blooded male are present but this rule is relaxed during Hajj where both male & female perform collectively as the chances of haram & evil actions are very low during most precious Muslim  gathering Hajj.
Same factor will be applied for Music if it has evil ingredients it will be called Haram or otherwise.  Normally in Muslim gathering we arrange following Mahafils of Music. 
1.    HAMAD praises and prays of blessings from Allah Almighty
2.   Naats   praises of Holy Prophet PBUH and his Seerat. 
3.   Munqabat  praise  In the honour of Sahaba, Ehlebate & noble personalities of islam
4   . Qawalis  specially in south Asia Pakistan,  india& Bangladesh Sufi poetry in form of Qawalis was introduced to see the popularity of music in Hind. These Qawalis were utilized as main source of spreading islamic messages and most of non believers got islamic message of peace harmony through these gathering.

If we state way declare the music un islamic then how we will provide islamic texture on electronic media i e Internet and other social media website which are main source of spreading the message in the world in these days, moreover, to compete media war against non believer we must have alternate texture for our young generation on social media.

Already we Muslims are suffering with unnecessary propaganda of terrorism, rights of women etc against Islam. It is need of the time that there should be a independent body comprising of renowned islamic scholars of all school of islamic thoughts and decide these on going issues in context of Halal & Haram directives, only than these confusion can be minimised in yougsters and newcomers of Islam.

Comment: I like to know the reason of negative marking. I have prepared my answer  after consulting a lot of sites on Internet and after the detailed search I came on the conclusion that listening music should be seen in the perspective of Haram and Halal directives.It means everything which is not clearly declared haram in quran as mentioned for use of alcohol cannot be declared haram provided there is evil ingredients available in it. That's why text me why I am awarded with negative marking it is not for challenging the evaluator but for my correction please.