# Is singing permissible in Islam?

Tags: fiqh, music

Is singing allowed in islam?

Is there any difference if the singer is a man or a woman?

What about if there is no music in the song?

Comment: Related: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/237/music-in-islam

Comment: @Al Ummat Why you deleted Assalamu Alaykum wa rahmatullah wa barakatuh?, I'm Muslim.

Comment: @MhdAljobory I do not like it ether, But people here made a move to remove the salaams and now we can not give it on our questions or answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It was narrated that Abu Balj said: "I heard Muhammad bin Hatib say:
>   'What differentiates between the lawful and the unlawful is the voice
>   (singing).'"
>
> أَخْبَرَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ عَبْدِ الأَعْلَى، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا خَالِدٌ،
>   عَنْ شُعْبَةَ، عَنْ أَبِي بَلْجٍ، قَالَ سَمِعْتُ مُحَمَّدَ بْنَ
>   حَاطِبٍ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ إِنَّ
>   فَصْلَ مَا بَيْنَ الْحَلاَلِ وَالْحَرَامِ الصَّوْتُ ‏"‏ ‏.‏

It is disliked almost haram for men to listen to women who sing.
Source one:[1](http://sunnah.com/urn/1033810)

Source two:[2](http://sunnah.com/urn/1033800)

> Salam ibn Miskin, quoting an old man who witnessed AbuWa'il in a
>   wedding feast, said: They began to play, amuse and sing. He united the
>   support of his hand round his knees that were drawn up, and said: I
>   heard Abdullah (ibn Mas'ud) say: I heard the apostle of Allah
>   (sallallahu 'alaihi wa sallam) say: Singing produces hypocrisy in the
>   heart.
>
> حَدَّثَنَا مُسْلِمُ بْنُ إِبْرَاهِيمَ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا سَلاَّمُ بْنُ
>   مِسْكِينٍ، عَنْ شَيْخٍ، شَهِدَ أَبَا وَائِلٍ فِي وَلِيمَةٍ فَجَعَلُوا
>   يَلْعَبُونَ يَتَلَعَّبُونَ يُغَنُّونَ فَحَلَّ أَبُو وَائِلٍ حَبْوَتَهُ
>   وَقَالَ سَمِعْتُ عَبْدَ اللَّهِ يَقُولُ سَمِعْتُ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى
>   الله عليه وسلم يَقُولُ ‏ "‏ الْغِنَاءُ يُنْبِتُ النِّفَاقَ فِي
>   الْقَلْبِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏

Songs sung by men or females under puberty, with a hand drum is permissible.

[It was narrated from 'Urwah that he narrated from Aishah that Abu Bakr As-Siddiq](http://sunnah.com/urn/1067250) :

> Entered upon her and there were two girls with her beating the duff
>   and singing, and the Messenger of Allah (sallallahu 'alaihi wa sallam)
>   was covered with his garment. He uncovered his face and said: "Let
>   them be there, O Abu Bakr, for these are the days of 'Eid." Those were
>   the days of Mina and the Messenger of Allah (sallallahu 'alaihi wa
>   sallam) was in Al-Madinah on that day." (Sahih)
>
> أَخْبَرَنَا أَحْمَدُ بْنُ حَفْصِ بْنِ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنِي
>   أَبِي قَالَ، حَدَّثَنِي إِبْرَاهِيمُ بْنُ طَهْمَانَ، عَنْ مَالِكِ بْنِ
>   أَنَسٍ، عَنِ الزُّهْرِيِّ، عَنْ عُرْوَةَ، أَنَّهُ حَدَّثَهُ أَنَّ
>   عَائِشَةَ حَدَّثَتْهُ أَنَّ أَبَا بَكْرٍ الصِّدِّيقَ دَخَلَ عَلَيْهَا
>   وَعِنْدَهَا جَارِيَتَانِ تَضْرِبَانِ بِالدُّفِّ وَتُغَنِّيَانِ
>   وَرَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم مُسَجًّى بِثَوْبِهِ - وَقَالَ
>   مَرَّةً أُخْرَى مُتَسَجٍّ ثَوْبَهُ - فَكَشَفَ عَنْ وَجْهِهِ فَقَالَ ‏
>   "‏ دَعْهُمَا يَا أَبَا بَكْرٍ إِنَّهَا أَيَّامُ عِيدٍ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ وَهُنَّ
>   أَيَّامُ مِنًى وَرَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم يَوْمَئِذٍ
>   بِالْمَدِينَةِ ‏.‏

Sources: Islamic Online University

Comment: What about if the singer of Anasheeds woman?

Comment: than the listener must not be a man.

Comment: @AlUmmat but in the example there are men listening to women singing?

Comment: The point of not listening to a man or a women is to keep you from your lust.

Answer (score 2):

Narrated Abu 'Amir or Abu Malik Al-Ash'ari:

> that he heard the Prophet saying, "From among my followers there will
>   be some people who will consider illegal sexual intercourse, the
>   wearing of silk, the drinking of alcoholic drinks and the use of
>   musical instruments....
>
> قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم: "ليكونن من امتي أقوام يستحلون الحر
>   والحرير والخمر والمعازف ..."  رواه البخاري

As for the singing to the women is forbidden in Islam, as a woman's voice is a rugged (awrah)

Comment: you mean the woman sound is "awrah" always ! or just when she's singing ?

Comment: Of course in singing,not the voice of women in general