# Why is the azan sung, if music is haram?

Tags: halal-haram, music, adhan, singing

I have long heard that music is prohibited in islam (haram). If it is so, then why is azan (call to prayer) sung ?
I have looked at these questions but haven't found an answer : [Is singing permissible in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/is-singing-allowed) and
[Is listening to Music Halal (permissible) or Haram (prohibited) in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/237/8530)

Comment: azan sung !!!, no  that is called qirat not singing both are very different technically.

Comment: @Zia It would be helpful to expound your comment. Qirat as per wiki is a method of recitation. So a method of recitation can have high and low notes, which is alright, but other/musical notes are haram?

Comment: its not sung, but recited; on the basis you're making the argument you might as well call speaking a form of singing.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, 
There is difference between music and song. Musical instruments are haraam not songs. Songs without music, without wrong intention and without wrong content is allowed in Islam.

Secondly,
Azaan is not really a song. It is offered melodiously to call people for prayer.

See this fatwa to read more about this:

[What is the ruling on Singing the Adhan and elongating the vowels. The hadith that speaks against singing implies getting paid also. Is singing the adhan by itself forbidden or not?](https://islamqa.info/en/10523)

About music read this fatwa: https://islamqa.info/en/5000

All kinds of Musical Instruments are forbidden except from daff in some cases. https://islamqa.info/en/20406

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly, all kinds of Singing and music are not haram (according to Shia). Actually some kinds of the music are considered as haram practice such as:

- Some kinds of singing like woman singing.
- Some musics which can be considered as Ghena...
- and so on.

Besides, we cannot consider Azan as a music. Since we can count it as a nice permissible  kind of reciting like reciting of Quran in difference voices.

Comment: This seems like your opinion, if not then provide further details because it isn't suitable answer for question.

Answer (score -1):

Music is not generally haram. It depends from person to person. Even in a pary if you feel a music is making you out of mind you cannot say other Muslim to leave, this is conditional due to each person.
There's a general law any thing that make you out of mind or destroy your body not in Allah way is haram because it affect your wisdom even for few seconds.

Comment: so there is no direct reference making MUSIC haram , is it ??

Comment: My references are iranian and you can see widely music is distributing legally and religiously every day in iran. No there's no due to my refrences.

Answer (score -3):

Very good question .Kindly try to know the actual meaning of Azan(call to prayer) in your mother tongue what ever it may be and then think over the meaning of the call to prayer 5 times a day.The call to payer is not a song and not set to any rhythm or style .In turkey call to prayer(Azan)is pronounced in turkish language and in Iran in the persian language.
The human voice was chosen for calling faithful Muslims to pray.The christians chose bells and jews trumpets for calling their faithful to prayer.Please keep enquiring.

Comment: Hello and welcome to [islam.se]. Instead of asking OP to go through the translation of the azaan it would be much better if you elaborated on what makes the azaan different from songs. And it does have rhythm and style (usually) way I see it. Please consider [edit]ing the answer and also go through [answer]. (In Iran azaan is certainly said in Arabic and not in Persian.)

Comment: And in Turkey it is Arabic also.