# What is the Islamic ruling regarding Beat-Boxing?

Tags: music

I know that the music is forbidden in Islam.  (Referring to this Question - [Music in Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/237/music-in-islam)), So what about Beat-Boxing?

I mean in general is the musical instrument not allowed or the sound?

Comment: forbidden? i think if comes to dance be forbbiden! add refrrence

Comment: Do you mean music?, see the link.

Comment: There's no instrument here except your vocal chords and mouth (or hands).. can be considered a subset of singing/humming a 'beat'?

Comment: Might be categorized under singing. I think I've seen percussions like drums allowed throughout a few points in history and modern 'islamic music', and beat-boxing matches percussion more closely than other musical instruments.

Comment: related: islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/is-singing-permissible-in-islam

Comment: > Yeah! it is Haraam as it is giving same result and producing
> instrumental sound. Check fatwa of Sheikh Muhammed Salih Al-Munajjid for more details: [https://islamqa.info/en/193426](https://islamqa.info/en/193426)

Answer (score 5):

Allah the almighty said:

> And of the people is he who buys the amusement of speech to mislead [others] from the way of Allah without knowledge and who takes it in ridicule. Those will have a humiliating punishment. ([31:6](http://legacy.quran.com/31/6))

Here a short interpretation of "the amusement of speech  لَهْوَ الْحَدِيثِ  lahu al-Hadith".

> As Ibn Mas`ud commented about the Ayah:
> (And of mankind is he who purchases Lahu Al-Hadith to mislead (men) from the path of Allah), he said, "This -- by Allah -- refers to singing.'' (source [qtafsir](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=1795))

So singing is an interpretation of lahu al-Hadith or the amusement of speech, but let's move to the sunnah:

In al-Bukhari's [al-Adab al-Mufrad](https://sunnah.com/adab/54/7) there's an interpretation of ibn 'Abbas:

> Ibn 'Abbas said about "There are some people who trade in distracting tales" (31:6) that it means singing and things like it.

which declares anything close to singing as lahu al-Hadith.
And on the authority of abu Ummamah:

> that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "Do not sell the female singers, nor purchase them, nor teach them (to sing). And there is no good in trade in them, and their prices are unlawful. It was about the likes of this that this Ayah was revealed: 'And among mankind is he who purchases idle talk to divert from the way of Allah (31:6).'" (Jami' at-Tirmidhi [1](https://sunnah.com/urn/742250) & [2](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/14/84))

This hadith is used by some scholars to declare all kinds of music instrumnents and all kinds of singing or likewise (for example beat-boxing as it is a sound made by the mouth and sounds like the sound of music instruments) as haram (see islamqa #[193426](https://islamqa.info/en/193426) and #[1867](https://islamqa.info/en/1867))

[This fatwa on islamweb](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/130379) -in Arabic- declares that scholars such as imam al-Qurtobi, imam at-Tabari, ibn as-Salah, ibn Rajab al-hanbali, ibn Qayyim and ibn Rajab al-Haythami have declared that there's a consensus about the prohibition of music instruments except with [daf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daf) (see for example in [sunan ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1319720), [sunan an-Nasai](https://sunnah.com/urn/1319720) and [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/urn/735680)).

While ibn Taymiyyah (according the same fatwa) declares a consensus among the scholars of the four schools of jurisprudence on the prohibition of all instruments of lahwu (amusement).

Answer (score 0):

This is *lahw*

> The great worshipper of his time, Ibn ‘Aabideen (may Allah have mercy
>   on him) said:
>
> **The musical instrument is not haram because of what it is; rather it is because it is intended for (haraam) entertainment, either for the
>   one who listens to it or for the one who plays it.**

One may then say "beat-boxing" is not actually playing an instrument. The response is as follows.

> He goes on to say:
>
> Islam does not differentiate between things that are similar at all,
>   and it does not regard as equal things that are different.

Due to the fact that beat boxing is fundamentally an imitation of instruments such as the drum, percussion and other instruments, it is ***haram***.

We can also rule this out due to the fact that beat boxing has been known to be used in environments where non-mahrams from opposite genders mix ; and anything which leads to *Fitnah* or *Haram* is within itself Haram.

In conclusion:

- Beatboxing is haram due to the environment it is associated with
- Beatboxing is also haram as it mimics the sound of instruments which are haram.
- If you are among those who indulge in this lahw, you should cease, for it is a transgression upon yourself to commit haram under the knowledge that it is so.
- It is also important to note that this form of music holds no roots in Islaam, rather, it was manufactured by the kuffar and perfected by those which indulge in evil acts. Hence, a good, practicing Muslim should avoid such acts in the fear that one minor evil shall lead to a major sin and transgression upon himself *(or herself.)*

Answer (score -1):

Salam,

As you say brother I don't think so that music is haraam if the music is not related to anything disrespecting to the God or you know some bad kind of behaviour then it prohibited and about your answer the beat boxing there is no issue in doing according to me because I dont think so it is a sort of way to disrespect the creator adn there is no mention about beat boxing because the beat boxing wasn't available at that time

Comment: Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer]. This answer can use evidence for support.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if I've said this exactly in my other answers or not, but the general idea is: lahv wa la'ab is haram.

**But WHAT is lahv and la'ab?**

Is it anything that's a waste of time? If that's your answer then watching the world cup Final is also technically a waste of time. But religion isn't that strict nor narrow.

Is lahv and la'ab the same in every country?
NO!!! Music that turns on Chinese people is different from Music that turns on Spanish people.

In general music which only tickles you to dance...music that get's people excited to do phase out is haram. I remember hearing a story of a person who once got sooo into the music that he got burnt by his own cigarette and didn't find out until the music was over.

Does beat-boxing fall into that category? The culture of the people you're surrounded decides that. (Culture does NOT decide whether or not homosexuality is haram or not. It's haram. It doesn't decide whether or not you should fast when it's 16 hours a day or not. You should. However the definition of playful music or what kind of behavior is unexpected between nahmahrams is somewhat decided by the norms aka *عُرف*.

My culture would say 'in it's current form' it's not used for lahv and la'ab. It's just a few moments of fun and beat-boxing are hard to dance and get a person to phase out. If your culture this sort of beat-boxing tickles you to dance or phases you out then AFAIK it's haram.

A side note. The reason Islam has a huge focus on not listening to music is:

From [treaties of rights](https://www.al-islam.org/divine-perspective-on-rights-a-commentary-of-imam-sajjads-treatise-of-rights/right-n-4-right-hearing) by Imam Sajjad. The Right of Hearing

> **حق السمع**
>
> *وَأَمَّا حَقُّ السَّمْعِ فَتَنْزِيهُهُ عَنْ أَنْ تَجْعَلَهُ طَرِيقًا إلَى قَلْبكَ إلا لِفُوهَةٍ كَرِيمَةٍ تُحْدِثُ فِي قَلبكَ خَيْرًا أَو
>   تَكْسِبُ خُلُقًا كَرِيمًا فَإنَّهُ بَابُ الْكَلامِ إلَى الْقَلْب
>   يُؤَدِّي إلَيْهِ ضُرُوبُ الْمَعَانِي عَلَى مَا فِيهَا مِن خَيْرٍ أَو
>   شَرِّ. وَلا قُوَّةَ إلا باللهِ.*
>
> And the right of hearing is to keep it pure by not making it the
>   direct pathway to your heart, except for noble words that establish
>   some good in your heart or grant you a noble trait. Indeed hearing is
>   the gateway through which various concepts reach the heart —whether
>   good or evil. And there is no power but in God.

A person who has listening to music of Kate Perry, Rihanna, Britney Spears all the time would find it hard to listen to lecture of great scholars like Nu'man Ali Khan or Ammar Nakhshawani. The Islamic idea is: Why delegate time to such, why give your heart to others while you can give your heart to Allah and reflection of his signs. Not proof, but statistically speaking our scholars are not fans of Yanni, Lady Gaga, etc. Similarly Allah has said:

> Allah has not made for a man two hearts in his interior. [Chapter
>   al-Ahzab verse 34](https://quran.com/33/4)

Answer (score -3):

All types of Musical instrument including Drum are Haram ***except Duf (which is one-side covered drum).***

**Singing and dancing are only allowed if they are done in front of the same gender and wearing proper clothes covering the whole body while dancing**. Singing or dancing in front of the opposite gender is prohibited as it appeals one's sex fluids in the body and may develop satanic feelings.

Listening to opposite gender's singing let his/her voice appeal satanic feelings so listening songs sung by opposite gender is also prohibited. **Listening decent songs sung by same gender is allowed.**

So in conclusion, ***beat boxing in front of same gender and Mahrams is allowed.***

Comment: Would you mind adding evidences to support your claims?

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Answers here should be elaborate, and focused on answering the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help), and refer to [how to answer questions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

It is haram if it is to imitate haram! The prophet said "**Whoever imitates a people the he is from them.**"  The Kuffar have their instruments to get a particular sound and if your mouth is trying to get this same sound, then it is no different than the instruments you were trying avoid in the first place. The mouth is imitating the instrument, and therefore it takes the same ruling.

Answer (score -5):

Salamalykum..
I believe that it sounds exactly like music and it takes its place.
It also distracts you from your Lord (Allah) SWT. Although I'm not sure,
It's better to be safe than sorry. So don't take the risk.

Comment: Salaams and welcome to Islam Stack Exchange. Unlike a typical Internet forum, answers here are expected to be more than mere personal opinon and guesswork (see: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/598/22).