# Is music allowed if it helps you think of God? (Sunni View)

Tags: music

Based on an [answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7797/what-is-the-islamic-definition-of-music/7925#7925) in another [question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7797/what-is-the-islamic-definition-of-music/), it seems that based on the Shia view, music is generally haraam, unless it helps you think of God?  Does the Sunni view have a similar scenario, or is music haraam 'end of story' according to the Sunni view, even if it helps you think of God?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be unanimous consensus that music is haraam across most mainstream schools of thought, Shia or Sunni.

However I think that may not be the intent of your question; Rather I can surmise that your question is that if music makes one think of God, should it be allowed?

There are two aspects to this question: the legalistic one and the "hikmah" one. While the former (legal) aspect is covered by the open injunction that music be eschewed, for the latter (hikmah or understanding) aspect, I guess we will have to fall back on personal experience and observation owing to the open nature of the question.

Music seems to be a major part of worship within most religious systems today (other than Islam, of course). Playing of music is not just allowed but even condoned in their centers of worship, so we find, for example, churches having organs, and devotees in temples in India singing "bhajans," kind of devotional music accompanied by musical instruments played to please God, or at least their conception of God.

Music however can be thought of as opium for the soul. There have been many instances in history where people consumed opium and other such stimulating drugs because it made them perform better. We find many examples of people in creative and artistic professions like writing or painting resorting to these methods to feel stimulated so that they write or paint better. Drugs do make one feel *and* perform better.

But then we all know the unwholesome effects of these mind-altering drugs on the human body; while they may enhance one's performance in the short-term by stimulating the mind temporarily, they only serve to destroy both the mind and body of the person who consumes them by making it "hollow" and unhealthy.

In a similar manner, so does music work on the human soul by "stimulating" it to think about God but ultimately destroying it by extinguishing that person's capacity for faith or imaan. The soul becomes "hollow," so to speak, and this becomes apparent in hypocrisy in behavior, and a disconnect between that person's beliefs and actions.

Just the way the human body requires good nutrition to remain healthy, so does the soul require the remembrance to God to sustain itself. This sustenance can only come about by doing *dhikr*, the best of which is recitation of the Qur'an and other *adhkaar* as reported in the books of Ahadeeth. A soul that gets "addicted" to music finds it difficult to absorb and retain the words and wisdom of the Book of Allah.

HTH.

Answer (score -1):

Should not forbid what is not forbidden by Allah SWT. Is Islamic songs haram? of course not, as long as it will help you draw closer to Allah SWT. For instance we will more easily remember Asmaul Husna if accompanied by beautiful music .. is it haram? Of course not. And if the Prophet Muhammad did not like the music, it does not mean that music is haram.

Added :

In one of the authentic hadith was mentioned about the things that are considered as the prohibition of singing and music proposition.

> Indeed there will be among my people, people who justify fornication,
>   silk, wine of the tools and neglect '. (Bukhari)

Because of this hadith found in al-Saheeh, then from side keshahihan had no problems. Saheeh isnaad although there are also some hadith scholars still doubt it.

But in terms of istidlal, the text of this hadith is general in nature, does not refer to specific tools to name specifically and explicitly. At this point actually occurs disagreement of the scholars. General proposition may be questioned if the company is still used as a basis to forbid something

Allah knows best