# Is music allowed in Islam? (three questions)

Tags: sharia, music, singing

In the name of God
Salamu Alaykum Wa Rahmatullahi Wa Barakatuhu
Hello everyone

I want to know these:

- Is listening to music allowed in Islam or not?
- If it is not allowed, does it means that all types of song is Haram?
- If it is not allowed, why some singers like Sami Yousif and Mahir Zain -who singing songs for Islam- are singing? does it means that Islamic musics allowed?

Thanks for you.
Dana.

Comment: Q1 already asked at http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/237/music-in-islam

Comment: Q2 already asked at http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7926/is-music-allowed-if-it-helps-you-think-of-god-sunni-view