# Are 'vocals only' nasheeds of Maher Zain permissible to listen to?

Tags: fiqh, salafi, singing

I recently learned that a nasheed is haram to listen to if it has sound effects which sound like musical instruments even if they are **'vocals only'** ([source](http://islamqa.info/en/107570)). However, I don't have much idea about musical instruments.

There are a number of nasheeds by **[Maher Zain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maher_Zain)** which are labelled as "Vocals only - No Music", and what I want to know is whether these nasheeds would fall under the prohibition in this fatwa (i.e. do any of the recorded vocals count as "effects which sound like musical instruments"?).

I am not interested in personal opinions and especially not in arguing about the validity of the fatwa itself; I expect answers to be backed by evidences, and these evidences must be compatible with the Salafi methodology used by IslamQA (the source of the fatwa itself).

Comment: I think nasheeds that only have vocals are subject to the words: if the words are find, then they're not haram, since the default state of things is halal except if they include something forbidden.

Comment: @TamerShlash Right, but if the vocal effects immitate musical instruments, then it becomes haram. See [this](http://islamqa.info/en/107570). My question is, does the nasheeds of Maher Zain contain such haram vocal effects?

Comment: Are you asking us to determine if the fatwa applies to any particular known aspect of Zain's nasheeds (if so, please specify exactly which), or asking us if anyone knows if any of Zain's nasheeds fall under the ruling (which would probably be unanswerable until you find someone who has (a) listened to every single one of his nasheeds and (b) knows enough about the fatwa to apply it).

Comment: @goldPseudo Yes, I want to know if it applies to the 'no-music' nasheeds of Maher Zain. And yes, I am looking for someone who could answer it. Feel free to edit the question to clarify things, but do not change the meaning of the question itself.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to clarify the question and scope according to my understanding of what you want; please look over the changes to see if I've misinterpreted anything.

Comment: @goldPseudo Thanks, it's much better now. Jazakum Allahu khairan.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the Islamic definition of music?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7797/what-is-the-islamic-definition-of-music)

Comment: from the above question, decide if those nasheeds are haram or not? or try asking there in the comments for further clarification or try running a bounty on it.