# Is the money I make from a club as a performer haram?

Tags: music

I'm an electronic music composer and I was wondering if I perform in a club, is the money that I get haram? The thing is, I'm not talking about normal performances and I won't be playing any music that talks about anything haram. I play electronic dance music that is just pure instrumentals and if it has any vocals, the vocals are usually inspiring and motivating. Anyways, my main question is, is it haram money if I'm not sure where my money is coming from? I'm asking this cause I've majored in music and I want to take music as a life time career and performing live will make me a lot of money. It's my dream since a kid to become a musician, and I'm pursuing it, I just want to know if God will punish me for the money I get.

Thank you a lot for your time.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on what you believe. Do you believe that Music is Haram? If you do so, that means income gained from it is also haram. If you believe that Music is not haram, rather what is said (no bad talk, sex talk, etc..) like many upcoming scholars then the income you earn will be halal Inshala.

Let me note that my opinion on Music that it is not Haram unless it has bad talk in it. Which is based on my true believe that the Prophet PBUH will not make something haram that Allah hasn't.

Comment: Exactly, I agree with that as well. As long as I'm not promoting anything bad but instead inspiring people and making them happy, I'm not doing anything wrong. Though will my money be haram if I performed in a club or festivals? Cause I'm receiving gig requests for up to 1000$ cause I've recently got signed to a big label, so I'm wondering if I should be happy about the money or actually upset lol.

Comment: by this logic...if someone believes killing is Halal then insha'a'llah its halal?!
I don't think so! It's all relative to what your sect says...not what me or you say

Comment: @Vazir There is nothing that says music is haram. There is indirect stuff in hadith that could be used to infer it but I think it uses too many assumptions and is too conservative to be worth while. After all in hadith its ok to celebrate using a drum like instrument. Otherwise killing is bad and I believe its throughout the Quran and the Old Testament.

Comment: @Jason
Please do search the keyword music on islam.stachexchange...and in major Islamic sects...many but not all say it's Haraam...those who do say it's haraam use plenty of narations
For instance take a look at this [question] (http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/237/music-in-islam).
Yet I don't understand why you are saying that...its all a matter of what your sect says... so if your sect tells you its Halal then Halal it is for you. لا یکلف الله نفساً الا وسعها