# I have given up playing music because it is haram, but I find myself addicted to pornography; should I return playing music occasionally?

Tags: music, pornography

I am not that a particularly devout person but I wish to become more devout.

I used to play music a lot but since it is haram, I left it.  Before, apart from my studies and salat, I used to play music in my free time. But after leaving it I am becoming addicted to pornography and I am missing my salat.

Before leaving music I used to pray salat and saum regularly, never forgot them, and I never saw porn before. But after leaving music I am going further astray day by day.  As long as I play music, I don't feel it has any bad effect over me. I was religious, meritorious and honest by the grace of Almighty Allah but now the scene is opposite.

Should I return playing music occasionally as it only made be better?

Comment: Who said playing music is haram? Watching porns instead is haram!

Comment: you can read about music in here: [Is listening to Music Halal (permissible) or Haram (prohibited) in Islam?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/237/is-listening-to-music-halal-permissible-or-haram-prohibited-in-islam)

Answer (score 1):

If you waste all of your time on instrument or playing video games or sleeping etc. it is not allowed. Muslims have daily jobs and they can not live like plants. If you only playing an instrument as hobby it is not problem, you can go on and try to stay away from woman voice, especially sensual woman voice when you playing or listening music.

Also you can read: http://www.questionsonislam.com/question/playing-guitar-permissible-islam

Comment: Sorry @Medi1Saif, "living like a plant" is an idiom not in real meaning.

Answer (score 0):

A hadith states that we are going to be asked about what we have done with our life's in the beginning of afterlife (in the grave) . If we have wasted it or not to be spesific.

> The two feet of the Son of Adam will not move from near his Lord on the Day of Judgement until he is asked about five (matters): about his life - how he spent it; about his youth - how he took care of it; about his wealth - how he earned it and where he spent it; and about that which he acted upon from the knowledge he acquired.

So you should neither watch porn or make music. You could do sports or practice another hobby but a halal one. The best option is to get a job. If you are studying it could be a part-time job.

May Allah the Most Forgiving forgive all our sins always. Ameen.

Answer (score 0):

You are being tested and misled by Satan. First it was music and then porn. You overcame music, felt guilty and started to pray. But Satan/Iblis put another 'waswasa' (Satan putting haram thoughts) of porn. I ran into the same problem so I put free security software on my smartphone to block porn sites and asked someone to put a password in the software and not to tell me. Then whenever I tried to access such content, I wasn't able to since I didn't have a password. I also increased my prayers besides obligatory ones to seek help from Allah. Also read Ayat-ul-Kursi morning and night for protection.