# Is music totally haram?

Tags: halal-haram, music

I've known that music is haram in just a couple days ago it seems hard to be free with music I intend to delete my music but before that, I have several questions related to music.

1. Is music allowed in marriage and in the Eid?
2. If music is totally haram, there are a lot of Islamic music such "Insyallah" by Maher Zain, "Asma Allah" by Sami Yusuf that praises Allah. Are those still categorized "haram"?
3. Is music haram regarded to the instrumental music (without lyric) or music/songs such as "Work" by Rihanna, Love "The Way You Lie" by Eminem?
4. How about DJ that uses electronics?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is listening to Music Halal (permissible) or Haram (prohibited) in Islam?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/237/is-listening-to-music-halal-permissible-or-haram-prohibited-in-islam?rq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is listening to Music Halal (permissible) or Haram (prohibited) in Islam?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/237/is-listening-to-music-halal-permissible-or-haram-prohibited-in-islam)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every kind of music is called "HARAM".  What makes a music "HARAM" is not who songs or who plays music.  It is the feeling and somehow the imagination that comes through it.  For example in Iran, According to Ruhullah Khomeini's thoughts, a music that is made to honor the ones who lost their bodies in war for islam, is halal.  But the music which describes the beauty of a girl, or the music which a women sings, is Haram. They say women have to sing somehow in the background when the main singer is a man.