# If someone is not distracted from Islam by music, is it still haram?

Tags: halal-haram, music

Music is considered haram because it is believed that it is a distraction from your creator, it diverts your attention from Islam and it could brain wash you. But what if someone isn't influenced by music at all, but listens to it?

For example, someone could be a strong good Muslim and listen to music at the same time but not being influenced just listening to it for fun or when studying and cleaning, it doesn't divert his/her mind from Allah they're not influenced by the lyrics and they don't listen to it on a daily basis and become addicted, just listening to it every now and then without being influenced or affected.

Comment: Music isn't haram par se based on the opinion of prominent scholars of the 4 madhabs and other modern scholars

Comment: Relevant: [Is listening to Music Halal (permissible) or Haram (prohibited) in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/26369/15201)

Answer (score -2):

Prophet said to Abu Musa: “O Abu Musa! You have been given one of the musical wind-instruments of the family of David!"
(Sahih Bukhari, Volume 6, Book61, Number 568, narrated by Abu Musa)

https://controversialislam.wordpress.com/music-banned-in-islam/

Comment: Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer]. What is the connection between Abu Musa's voice and music being halal or haram?