# Which prominent Sunni scholars say music is not haram?

Tags: sunni, islamic-scholar, music

In a comment to [If someone is not distracted from Islam by music, is it still haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/39100/17163), we have:

> Music isn't haram par se based on the opinion of prominent scholars of the 4 madhabs and other modern scholars -- [Medi1Saif](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/39100/if-someone-is-not-distracted-from-islam-by-music-is-it-still-haram#comment66431_39100)

This makes me wonder who precisely Medi1Saif is talking about.  This is at odds with the top answer to [Is listening to Music Halal (permissible) or Haram (prohibited) in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/237/17163) which says "...only an exceedingly small minority believe it to be permissible."

**Question**: Which prominent Sunni scholars say music is not haram?

Comment: I got a list of mujtahideen who deemed that music was permissible. Do you want that list in an answer?

Comment: @Armaan: While it sounds interesting, it wasn't what I had in mind for this question (i.e., they're not really scholars).

Comment: Al-Ghazaly is one of those and i've heard that imam Malik wanted to become a singer but his mother guided him by sending him to the course of Rabi'a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following are some of the most prominent scholars in our history who, deemed music permissible:

- **Abdullah bin Ja’far bin Abi Talib** (al-Aqd al-Fareed 6/12)
- **Sh. Abu Hamed al-Ghazali** (vol. 6 pg. 1150 al-Ihyaa’)
- **Imam al-Shawkani** (Ibtal da’wa al-Ijmaa ala mutlaq al-Sama’)
- **Imam ibn Hazm** (Al-Muhallah)
- **Imam Abdul-Ghani al-Nablusi** (Idaahat al-Dalalaat fee sama’ al-alaat)
- **Sultan al-Ulema al-Iz ibn Abdul-Salam** (Rislat al-Sama’)
- **Al-Qadi Ibn Qutaiba al-Daynoor** (al-Rukhsah fi al-Sama’)
- **Imam Ibn Tahir al-Qaysirany** (pg. 31 al-Sama’)
- **Imam al-Thahabi** (al-Rukhsah fil-Ghinaa wa al-Turb)
- **Abu Talib al-Makky** (Qoot al-Quloob)
- **al-Qady Ibn Al-Araby al-Makky** (Ahkam al-Quran vol. 3 pg. 1494)
- **Sh. Yusuf al-Majishoon the prominent Muhaddith** (#3399 ibn al-Khuthayma)
- **Ibn Daqeeq al-Eid** (Iqtinas al-Sawanih)
- **Sh. Jad Ali jad al-Haqq** (fatawah #3280)
- **Sh. Mahmood Al-Shaltoot** (pg. 375 fatawaah)

**Note:** *This is what I found so far so there might be more scholars which I will add later. Feel free to edit and add more scholars.*

Comment: Please clarify the source of the list. I know that some of the list is accurate, e.g., Dr. Shaltoot through a one-on-one discussion. But I am not too sure about the entire list. _Al-Rukhsah Fil-Ghinaa' Wa Al-Tarab_ by Al-Dhahabi (not his book — an abridged version of _Al-Imta' Bi Ahkam Al-Sama'_ by Ibn Taghlib) does not address music, but discusses poetry without instruments. Al-Shawkani in _Ibtal Da'wa Al-Ijmaa'_ did not say music was permitted; rather, he posed the different views to say there was no ijmaa', and he separated the topics of instruments vs. poetry.

Comment: Do any of them make a distinction with regard to kind of music? It seems like the hand drum (daff) is allowed by a lot more, as is unaccompanied singing, than e.g. string or wind instruments or singing plus instruments.

Comment: @III-AK-III     http://www.virtualmosque.com/islam-studies/sciences-of-quran-and-hadith/regarding-the-permissibility-of-music/

Comment: @G.Bach — Yes, they do, and this includes hand drums as well as string or wind instruments.

Comment: @Armaan — Thank you for the link. After reading the article, unfortunately, it did not quote or provide clear reference to where the listed scholars discussed the matter, or declared their opinion.