# What is the solid evidence that music is haram?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, hadith-interpretation, music

AssalamuAlaikum,

I think Music regarding haram activities is definitely wrong to listen to, but what about other types of music?

I came across this interpretation in the comments of this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tk1ESOU7Dsk):

> "There is solid evidence to say that music is not haram, even the prophet pbuh allowed it, I'll show you the ahadith:
>
> "'Aishah narrated that when a woman was married to an Ansari man, the Prophet (peace be on him) said, " 'Aishah, did they have any entertainment? The Ansar are fond of entertainment.'' (Reported by al-Bukhari.)
>
> Ibn 'Abbas said, " 'Aishah gave a girl relative of hers in marriage to a man of the Ansar. The Prophet (peace be on him) came and asked, 'Did you send a singer along with her?' 'No,' said 'Aishah. The Messenger of Allah (peace be on him) then said, The Ansar are a people who love poetry. You should have sent along someone who would sing, 'Here we come, to you we come, greet us as we greet you.' " (Reported by Ibn Majah.)
>
> 'Aishah narrated that during the days of Mina, on the day of 'Eid al-Adha, two girls were with her, singing and playing on a hand drum. The Prophet (peace be on him) was present, listening to them with his head under a shawl. Abu Bakr then entered and scolded the girls. The Prophet (peace be on him), uncovering his face, told him, "Let them be, Abu Bakr. These are the days of 'Eid." (Reported by al-Bukhari and Muslim.)
>
> In his book, Ihya ulum al-deen, (In the quarter on "Habits", in the book Listening to Singing.), Imam al-Ghazzali mentions the ahadith about the singing girls, the Abyssinians playing with spears in the Prophet's Mosque, the Prophet's encouraging them by saying, "Carry on, O Bani Arfidah," his asking his wife, 'Aishah, "Would you like to watch?" and standing there with her until she herself became tired and went away"
>
> — Sheik Yusuf Al Qaradawi the lawful and the prohibited
>
> As for the Haidth about some Muslims making music halal, there is an alternate narration that reads as follows:
>
> "Some people of my ummah will drink wine, calling it by another name, while they listen to singers accompanied by musical instruments. Allah will cause the earth to swallow them and will turn some of them into monkeys and swine." (Reported by Ibn Majah.)
>
> Only Allah knows best"

What is the response to this, are these references weak? Usually, when I research the haram status of music, all of the prohibitions come from the fact that modern mainstream music is crude and sexual, but that doesn't account for all music.

I am just searching for knowledge and open to understanding the debate, and Allah Knows Best.

Comment: Many scholars consider hand drums to not be haram. But, otherwise all your narrations seem to be about singing and reciting poetry which noone considers haram.

Comment: How does this question differ from [Is listening to music halal?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/237/17163)

Comment: I wonder if we need ten or more questions about music being halal or haram so that anybody could express his view. The matter is a discussed matter among scholars there are prominent scholars considering it halal while there are many scholar considering it haram we will never be able to make an end for this discussion as both sides have good and strong evidences for their view. So basically this question should have been covered somewhere on the site.

Answer (score -1):

> “People among my nation will drink wine, calling it by another name, and musical **instruments will be played for them** and singing girls (will sing for them). Allah will cause the earth to swallow them up, and will turn them into monkeys and pigs.” ([Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/36/95))

This is evidence that musical instruments are not allowed, as they are mentioned with things that are haram and Allah punishes people for listening to them.

As to all your ahaadeeth, none of them involve musical instruments (except for hand drums which most agree are allowed). They are just speaking of singing or reciting poems which is completely allowed. In fact, the Prophet (SAW) had a Sahabah named Hassan ibn Thabit who used to write and recite his poetry in the Masjid of the Prophet (SAW).

> "From among my followers there will be some people who will consider illegal sexual intercourse, the wearing of silk, the drinking of alcoholic drinks **and the use of musical instruments, as lawful**. And there will be some people who will stay near the side of a mountain and in the evening their shepherd will come to them with their sheep and ask them for something, but they will say to him, 'Return to us tomorrow.' Allah will destroy them during the night and will let the mountain fall on them, and He will transform the rest of them into monkeys and pigs and they will remain so till the Day of Resurrection." (Bukhari)

Notice how the use of musical instruments is mentioned along with everything else which no one can deny is evil, and Allah punishes people for it. And when it is said they will 'consider it lawful', the implication is given that it is not indeed lawful, and it is solidified by the fact that they are punished for it.

Imagine a police officer telling citizens: "There will be those among you who will consider stealing, money laundering, fraud, and drinking apple juice legal. They will be arrested and jailed." You don't know much about this society, but you know apple juice is illegal.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: This is very flimsy evidence to base a ruling on and just looks like cherry-picking: The first hadith you quote is *hasan*, the second one is barely relevant, the third and fourth aren't even referenced (and best I can tell, are *da'if* and *hasan* respectively), the last one isn't even a hadith of the prophet.

Comment: Also, you contradict yourself when you say that singing is completely allowed when the exact evidence you're laying out with the first and fourth hadith would also apply to the "singing girls" who are mentioned right along with musical instruments and other things which "no one can deny is evil".

Comment: @goldPseudo . Singing slave girls are not permissible, is that hard to accept. Not singing or reciting poetry. The fact they are slave girls is important. As in promiscuity, vulgarity etc.

Comment: I have no interest in arguing with you. The question is asking for "solid evidence", and this answer does not provide it. See also https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1438/22

Comment: Jazak Allah khairun for the answer, but please can you tell me why all that is mentioned in the hadith is regarded separately, instead of The Prophet (Pbuh)describing a particular group of people that do all these things together. Usually wealthy men Muslim or not go to events to drink alcohol, wear silk (expensive clothes), fornicate, and watch singing woman/music for entertainment. It seems to me like these men are being described and being told of their outcome. The first three things are clear major sins accompanied by observing women in a non halal way. Whilst the music part is ambiguous?

Comment: to clarify when I say the first three things are clear major sins its because it is clearly listed in Quran and many Hadith as wrong. Whereas this is the only hadith cited in the regard of music.

Comment: @AAK . If you read the hadith from bukhari it is specifically saying those people will 'consider' it lawful, as in it isn't lawful but they consider it

Comment: Otherwise it wouldn't make sense. Why would he (SAW) add a thing they 'consider' to be lawful, if it actually is lawful in Islam, and then say they will be punished for it? The context of the hadith is listing their wrongdoings, and considering musical instruments lawful is listed among with everything else.

Comment: Imagine a police officer telling citizens: "There will be those among you who will consider stealing, money laundering, fraud, and selling and buying alcohol legal. They will be arrested." You don't know much about this society, but you know alcohol is illegal.

Comment: oh alright I see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74716/discussion-between-the-z-and-aak).

Comment: @goldPseudo . I added a hadith from Bukhari. Sahih solid evidence.