# is being a bts fan haram?

Tags: halal-haram

is being a bts fan haram ?

As’Salamu ‘Alaykum

i am a sixteen year old girl and i am obsessed with a boy band called “bts”, i talk about them more than I have of Allah SWT and Prophet Mohammed PBUH ( i always say astaghfirullah when such thoughts come a lot instead Allah SWT and Prophet Mohammed PBUH ), bts are seven boy's in their twenties and they’re not like other boy bands (aggressive music, bad words), they spread positivity through their music ( no bad words, reminding people to love themselves ) and also have done and are still doing charity work. is it okay to be a

1. a bts fan
2. attending bts concerts
3. attend bts related gatherings
4. my friends parent told her that if she’s a fan of someone and loves them a lot but if the person is a christian, on the day of judgement she will go to hellfire with them. is this true ?

there are many muslim girls and boys who are doing the same thing obsessing over “bts” and forgetting Allah SWT and their are some like me, who are seeking for answers if it is okay to be a fan. not obsessing but just a fan of seven boys, who are singers spreading a positive message.

yubarikuk Allah wu wa ʿalaykumu s-salām.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is listening to music halal?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/237/is-listening-to-music-halal)

Answer (score 3):

If you ask any Muslim. Which book is most authentic on earth after quran. They will say sahih al bukhari.

so in Sahih al bukhari -

> Prophet (saw) says, From among my followers there will be some people
> who will make haram things halal, that is illegal sexual intercourse,
> the wearing of silk, the drinking of alcoholic drinks and the use of
> musical instruments, as halal.

References
Sahih al-Bukhari, 5590
Sahih al-Bukhari, Vol. 7, Book of Drinks, Hadith 494
Sahih al-Bukhari, Book of Drinks, Hadith 494

look the prediction by prophet (saw) is being true in font of our eyes. Please don't try make haram things halal because you like it. Even i like listening music but i try to not because it's haram.

Maybe you  like BTS but being fan of them is haram. Even if they make positive songs. But it's haram because of musical instruments. Please don't try to make it halal because you like their musics. There are many article that will mislead people, thinking music is halal. That's why i am giving you clear proof. If you can't stop listening to musics. then take time to stop listening to it. Not try make it halal.

> But perhaps you hate a thing and it is good for you; and perhaps you
> love a thing and it is bad for you. And Allah Knows, while you know
> not.

Surah Baqarah - 216

Being a BTS and attending to their concerts is not permissible. Didn't understand your No. 4 question. But you can be friends with non-muslims. So long as they don't effect you in a bad way. Like your non-muslim friend is making you do haram things. Instead you should give Islamic dawah to them.

I Recommend you to watch "Nasheed(Islamic songs without musical instruments)" from youtube. But beware very few Nasheed are also used by musical instruments.

Answer (score 0):

You may listen to their songs if they spread positivity.  But you can only listen to them without music.  Search "Acapella" or "vocals only".  The voice alone isn't explicitly Haraam.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Please check out a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site to learn how this site works. Thanks for your answer. It is even better if you support your answer by citing sources.

Answer (score 0):

is being a bts fan haram?

so this is the true answer of this question...i asked this question from a well known scholar in islam, it is said that anything that the satan dances on is haram,so aslong as bts does not use instruments in there songs and only use vocal sound it's halal but since they use instruments it's haram listening to their music..

if you only stan them and support them you will still go to hell because your supporting people who make and spread music,and if you just say your army and just have some pics of them in private it depends on you, if you see them as your brothers it's halal if not it's even haram to have pics of unknown men.

Answer (score -2):

There is no explicit mention of *music* and *musicality* and certainly not *bands* being haram in the Qur'an, nor in Hadith, some interpetations of verses correspond to outright banning of music on the basis of it poisoning the mind, certainly. But the interpetations are not largely agreed upon nor enforced in Islam.

As long as you watch out for your own internal beliefs you are not doing wrong in Islam's right.