# As I believe only in Quran & not the Hadiths, is music Halal for me?

Tags: music, quran-only

I don't believe in Hadiths because they were written 200 years after the death of Prophet Muhammad (SAW). I only believe in Allah and Allah's book the Quran.

So my  question is as there is not a direct verse in Quran which tells music is haraam, I know verses of surah luqman in which Allah says idle talk but everything that is haram Allah clearly mentions in Quran by their name example alcohol , gambling etc all these things are haraam clearly mentioned the name but not for music.

Allah says in the Quran that Allah has no shortage of words if Allah wants to make music haraam Allah can clearly mentioned the word music

**Can anyone help me  with my question?**

**NOTE: PLEASE DON'T GIVE ME THOSE HADITHS SOURCES AS I ALREADY MENTIONED I DON'T BELIEVE IN THEM**

Comment: How do you know about Muhammd's life then? Not believing in hadith is rejecting his prophethood as you indirectly say he didn't do his job well and didn't leave any traces.

Comment: No I'm not saying that the prophet didn't do his job correcly he did everything that allah tells him to do but I'm telling that the hadith's can be changed compared to the real incident that happened at the time of prophet  because hadith were written 200 years after the death of prophet it's not 2 days or 2 months it's 200 years and they wrote the hadith by their memory and if human can change bible and Torah then hadith's can also be changed so that's why id ont believe in it brother I believe in prophethood

Comment: That's not true hadith was already compiled 50 years after his death. And some sahabah did write it while he was alive. In fact the qur'an was only compiled as a whole book 20 years after his death in the final version. And finally the hadith doesn't 100% support declaring music as haram while the main evidence for those holding this position is the verse from surat Luqman.

Comment: @uzairkhan Out of curiosity, how do you know how much zakat to pay, how rakahs to pray in each salah, the different acts to be performed in Umrah & Hajj, what is Halal & Haram in marriage with your spouse, what invalidates a fast etc if you don't trust the Hadiths. I agree some Hadiths have been fabricated BUT  we have a complete science regarding the authenticity of Hadiths and their tafsir. I don't know if you are one of the so called modern sects in Islam who call themselves the "Quranists" but I request you first research on the subject with a qualified Alim before coming to a conclusion.

Comment: Where's the source from which you got that Hadith was written '200 years' after Prophet's death? Did you verify that source? It would be quite ironic if you don't even know the original source and authenticity of this number and then talk about authenticity of ahadith that has undergone centuries of scrutiny and authentication, more than any compilations of text in existence.

Comment: You may also refer to [Authenticity of hadith similar to famous hadith on end of times in bukhari](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/56642/authenticity-of-hadith-similar-to-famous-hadith-on-end-of-times-in-bukhari/56649#56649)

Answer (score 1):

Allah (ﷻ) spoke on the serious sins plaguing mankind, not specifically on ALL sins that ever existed. To know the rest of the sins that should be avoided, Muslims turn to the Sunnah.. and we do so because Allah (ﷻ) Himself said He sent the Prophet (ﷺ) to us to explain to us e.g., expand on the little details.

These references I compiled may benefit you: [Following the Sunnah: Established in the Qur'an](https://veiledink.wordpress.com/2016/10/15/following-the-sunnah-established-in-the-quran/)

There's a lot of specific sins not mentioned by name in the Qur'an. e.g., the Sunnah tells us the sin of starving a cat by depriving it of food and not letting it out to hunt for itself. Does this mean this action is then NOT a sin since it's not mentioned in the Qur'an specifically? SubhanAllah. No.

The evil of musical instruments themselves is not specifically mentioned in the Qur'an BUT the effects of music are not at the same level of harm as that of alcohol (impairing judgement, killing the body) and gambling (causing people major losses in wealth and leading to bawls).

Allah (ﷻ) did (in general) warn of heedlessness though. Music, among other things, causes many people to become heedless. Then the Prophet (ﷺ) confirmed that music is unlawful and prophesied that people would in the future try to make it lawful.

I'll respond back later regarding you hadith recording objection iA.

Comment: As for your hadith recording rejection, the same Sahabah through whom the Qur'an was transmitted to us (i.e., Qur'an didn't fall down from the sky as a book into your lap) also transmitted hadith in the same exact way. So please think logically.. as it makes no sense to assume they'd think to write down the revelation (Qur'an) ASAP but not the Prophet's explanation of the revelation (sunnah).

Answer (score -1):

Salam...
Music deals with frequencies.
At 55hz a cat purr can heal ligaments in the human body.
At 550hz you can dissolve cancer cells.
432hz is what the earth puts off.
High frequencies drive lower level beings and entities away.
(Bad jinn, etc)
All chants and prayers in all religions have a similar time.
Bells drive em away too.
Salt puts off a very high resonance frequency.
Allah SAID let there be light and there was.
A scientific study was done to where they used different frequencies to make an air bubble implode on itself and create super bright ultraviolet light using sound alone.
Music itself in my opinion isn't haram or halal.
But how the wielder uses it determines wether or not it is.
If a musician (wether he has knowledge of frequencies or not) uses his or her songs to make the masses dumber and lack empathy twrds their actions then yes it's being used in a harmful way.
If the musician uses music to help the masses grow as individuals and maintain a sahih and direct path then I personally see nothing wrong with it.
Just my opinion not basing it off of anything I know about the quran.