# Is listening to music Haram?

Tags: halal-haram, music

As-salamu alaykum, I hope all of you are doing well. As a muslim who finds joy when sad when listening to music, I want to know if it is haram. I have heard that if music does not give you bad, haram, thoughs it is permissable. However, I have also heard that any kind of music is haram. Can someone please explain to me if this is haram or halal. If so, please explain why. Goodbye and thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is listening to music halal?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/237/is-listening-to-music-halal)

Comment: In addition to the answer linked in the above comment, there's a rich variety of views in a similar Quora question about this: https://www.quora.com/q/islam-and-muslims/Why-is-music-haram

Answer (score -1):

This question comes up over and over again on Islamic discussion boards. Some scholars say that listening to music is haram outright regardless of the type of music, giving their proofs and evidences, while others say it depends on the type of music you are listening to. For example, music which promotes or glorifies that which is sinful. Allah knows best.

Answer (score -1):

Anything that incite you to vulgarity and obscenity should not be heard.

So technically it depends on the type of the music you are into and its composition. Otherwise music is like a food for our souls. Try Qawwali (Sufi) music, one of the best thing.