# Is it permissible to go to a high school party - organised by the teachers?

Tags: sin, shaitan

Please i will be very thankfull if you answer my question.

So, first,  i asked my parents and they said that i should go. The only problem concerning me is that there will be music.

What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Allaah says in the glorious Quran :-
" And if Shaytaan causes you to forget, then after the remembrance sit not in the company of those people who are the zaalimoon (polytheists and wrong-doers, etc.)." [al-An'aam 6:68]

Where a forbidden event occurs, there will be thousands more sins. I am afraid that someone will allow you to go there and in the near future you will commit sins by supporting them. So, you shouldn’t go to such parties. And Fend off yourself (in sha allah) from the unimaginable hurtful Fire.

See also -https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/596

Answer (score 0):

What is going to be happening at the party? Evaluate the activities and determine if you should go or not. For example, If they are mubah (permissible) activites such as sports then that shouldn't be an issue but if there is dancing and mixing of the sexes, then you shouldn't go.

In regards to your concern about music, there are different Islamic views about the permissibility of music which you can read here: https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/77139/51636