# Are sounds that don't really imitate musical instruments haram?

Tags: music

Is it permissible to make sounds that imitate not the musical instruments but other sounds? like gun sound, horse gallop sound, explosion sound, stepping sound, particles dropping sound, opening a door sound etc. Note that these sounds require you to beat some stuff or blow into some stuff just like the musical instruments (like beating a table, beating a metal etc). Making these sounds may even require you to use something like musical instruments and edit the sound in an audio editing program and these sounds are really pleasing to hear although they are not really music. And sometimes they may resemble some musical instruments like some gun sounds do resemble musical instruments.

If you want samples of these go to this site. https://www.soundsnap.com/tags/pump_action_0

However don't explore this site much as it may contain music.

Comment: maybe the definition of music is the matter hear. isnt it not like music in the end?. does it not affect the person how the normal mainstream music does?. whats haram is haram no matter what approach you take towards it. an example is, no matter what you make of pork, its still haram.

Comment: @ahmadnazeem but the intention is not to create music. And it doesn't really affect a person like normal mainstream music does. Like imagine a video of a gun shooting. And the video is silent. Now I make some kind of gun sound by beating some stuff and edit it and add it to that video. So it feels more real. Would that be haram? (But imagine the sound is pretty satisfying to hear)

Comment: The [fatwa of Sheikh Assim Al-Hakeem](https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=2002623126585334&id=302244863289844) can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Any reasoning based on direct and literal hadith interpretation may lead to the conclusion that making music with a wide range of musical instruments is to be considered haram. However, the same literal applicaction of hadith cannot lead to any conclusion about sampled sounds.

In the discussion about music in general, see [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/237/is-listening-to-music-halal?answertab=votes#tab-top), the majority opinion among present scolars that it can be concluded from hadith that music is haram is supported by the argument that music per se distracts from God and good Din, whereas many scolars of past times (most prominent among them Imam al-Ghazali a.s.) state that music per se is neither good nor evil but rather the purpose decides whether it is good (mubah / mustahab) or bad (makruh / haram).

As -in contrast to music - none can be interpreted as a general interdiction to produce a sound, producing sound with a digital sampler cannot be declared haram, see also [here](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/askimam/125634/sound-effects-in-computers-etc-and-applications-softwares-etc/)

It is thus only the purpose for which the sound is produced that may decide whether it is good (mubah / mustahab) or bad (makruh / haram).

Comment: so one can wonder, if something haram is done with the intention of good, will that make it haram or halal?. as you have mentioned the purpose determines the outcome. maybe what we have here is a conflict of definition of the word music, as the arabic word that appear in quran and hadith is much broader in concept/meaning.....my comment is directed only towards constructive argument.

Comment: In this case, I said that the means is mubah, and only the purpose may change that. But for jihad war, the prophet really taught that the purpose made the means (killing, haram) allowable.

Comment: @ahmadnazeem If you want some samples for the sounds I wanted to mean you can go to this site (https://www.soundsnap.com/tags/pump_action_0) but don't explore the site much as it may contain music. The site has shotgun sounds and they are satisfying to hear. I don't know if imitating these sounds is halal or not if it's made by beating some stuff or blowing into some stuff like musical instruments.

Comment: @MahirLabib In short: Imitating sounds is halal. Just wanted to go a bit further and make you think about what you are doing with those sounds cause I don't know it.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the rulings, the first thing that matters is which Islamic religion are you from and which world do you follow ?! Because such rulings have different jurisprudential rulings according to different Islamic religions.
However, the jurisprudential rule of music in Shiite Islam is such that most Shiite scholars do not consider music absolutely forbidden, but different music has different rules.
Most scholars forbid music that is suitable for dance parties and corruption. Or music that raises the excitement to the point that the intellect can not work properly.

As you said, they are just imitations of the small sounds around us, and they are a long way from the right music for dance parties. I do not think that such sound effects are forbidden because they will not harm the rationality of the listener.