# Is it haram to listen Maher Zain's songs?

Tags: music

I have been listening to Maher Zain (A Islamic music creator) since 2014. Through his whole career he made only Islamic music. His songs encourages people to follow the Islamic path. His all lyrics are praising to Allah & prophet Muhammad.
So is it haram to listen Maher Zain's songs ?

Comment: There's an entire Q/A for the permissibility of Music, which you can check out here: https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/77139/51636

Answer (score 0):

His nasheeds have musical instruments in the background, however he has nasheeds that are just audio which you can listen to as an alternative but try to steer away from one’s with music

Answer (score 0):

If any song includes music, it will be haram. However, if it includes duff only, it will be mubah. And the music must not contain any haram ideas, meanings, and leading.

For a more detailed answer, read an article in Islamqa about it-

[Is Music Haram? Fatwa no: 5000](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/5000/is-music-haram)