# is making music haram? Im a music producer

Tags: halal-haram

I'm a music producer. I make no vocal lofi music. and I also make video game music. so is this hobby of mine haram?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is listening to music halal?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/237/is-listening-to-music-halal)