# Music instrument in nasheed / Islamic song

Tags: halal-haram, music

Assalamu alaikum brother and sister.

I want to know if music instrument is allowed in islam or not , I'm saying about playing music instrument in nasheed / Islamic song or listening to nasheed that has a music one. Is it permissible to do? Or it is haram .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is listening to music halal?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/237/is-listening-to-music-halal)

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, prophet (s.a) didn't explicitly mention the musical instruments that are allowed and that are not allowed. Also, he didn't mention in which all situations any musical instrument(s) can be used. (like in Eid, weddings..) . These rulings are created by later scholars who go through hadiths and when they see a particular instrument being used in a particular situation, they say that instrument is allowed in that situation. Problem is not all situations and instruments get recorded in the hadith and we cannot say all other instruments and situations it is forbidden. Like in modern world music is generated electronically and we have them in our ring tones, calling bells, computer start up/shut down etc. We cannot categorically say all this are forbidden (haraam) because it is not mentioned in hadith.

We should be very careful when declaring something as forbidden or allowed (haraam or halaal)

> But say not - for any false thing that your tongues may put forth,-
> "This is lawful, and this is forbidden," so as to ascribe false things
> to Allah. For those who ascribe false things to Allah, will never
> prosper. Quran 16:116

Comment: Then what should i do, I'm the one who like to listen nasheed with music . But i afraid it will make sin... Or is it depending on my niyyah (intention)?

Comment: Personally I hear Islamic songs most of time with music.